# How to remove multiple duplicates from list whenever we give a duplicate element

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I remove repeated elements from ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203984/how-do-i-remove-repeated-elements-from-arraylist)

I have one list in that elements like

```
[10,11,12,10,12,13,10,12,11,11].
```

The requirement is when ever we enter one duplicate value remove the remaining duplicate values.
Ex:if we remove the 10 then automatically remove two tens.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203984/how-do-i-remove-repeated-elements-from-arraylist and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778260/how-to-remove-arraylist-duplicate-values - possible duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`List.removeAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29) coupled with [`Collections.singleton`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singleton%28T%29).

```
final List<Integer> list
    = new LinkedList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(10, 11, 12, 10, 12,
          13, 10, 12, 11, 11));
list.removeAll(Collections.singleton(10));
assert list.equals(Arrays.asList(11, 12, 12, 13, 12, 11, 11));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `removeAll()` method of list as:

```
List<Integer> tempList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
tempList.add(10);
list.removeAll(tempList);
```

or you can use `Collections.singleton()` as:

```
list.removeAll(Collections.singleton(10));
```

Comment: I don't think this completely answers the OP's question.