# How to efficiently remove duplicates from an array without using Set

Tags: java, arrays, optimization

I was asked to write my own implementation to remove duplicated values in an array. Here is what I have created. But after tests with 1,000,000 elements it took very long time to finish. Is there something that I can do to improve my algorithm or any bugs to remove ?

**I need to write my own implementation - not to [use `Set`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10056729/java-remove-duplicates-from-an-array), `HashSet` etc. Or any other tools such as iterators. Simply an array to remove duplicates.**

```
public static int[] removeDuplicates(int[] arr) {

    int end = arr.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < end; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < end; j++) {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {                  
                int shiftLeft = j;
                for (int k = j+1; k < end; k++, shiftLeft++) {
                    arr[shiftLeft] = arr[k];
                }
                end--;
                j--;
            }
        }
    }

    int[] whitelist = new int[end];
    for(int i = 0; i < end; i++){
        whitelist[i] = arr[i];
    }
    return whitelist;
}
```

Comment: What restrictions are placed on you? Can you `sort`? You can certainly improve on this O(n^3) implementation. This algorithm should be O(nln(n)) in the optimal case.

Comment: Well yes, you've got an O(n^3) algorithm... that doesn't sound like a good idea to me.

Comment: you can use `Set<Integer>` ?

Comment: You asked this in [Codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/29210/java-remove-duplicates-from-an-array), too. There is [an answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/29212/27897), too.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Yes, the array can be sorted.

Comment: @sanbhat I was asked to write my own implementation, not to use any tools.

Comment: @Tichodroma I asked, but there isn't too much attention there, so I asked it here.

Comment: @ashur Perhaps take a look at the answer there. It will help you.

Comment: What's the range of the `int`s in the arrays? If it's known and small you can do a bucket sort and remove duplicates as you go.

Comment: @BoristheSpider values inside array doesn't matter really. But I can assume that range is between 0-1000.

Comment: Well, you already have two answers in the [code review forum](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/29210/java-remove-duplicates-from-an-array)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Remove Duplicates from an Array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10056729/java-remove-duplicates-from-an-array)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for a code review. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remove repeated elements from ArrayList?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203984/how-do-i-remove-repeated-elements-from-arraylist)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Algorithm: efficient way to remove duplicate integers from an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532819/algorithm-efficient-way-to-remove-duplicate-integers-from-an-array)

Comment: code can benefit by sorting the array and then using that information to modify that array in place and getting a new end index.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since this question is still getting a lot of attention, I decided to answer it by copying [this answer from Code Review.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/29216/5799):

> You're following the same philosophy as the bubble sort, which is
>   very, very, very slow. Have you tried this?:
>
> - Sort your unordered array with [quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort). Quicksort is much faster
>     than bubble sort (I know, you are not sorting, but the algorithm you
>     follow is almost the same as bubble sort to traverse the array).
> - Then start removing duplicates (repeated values will be next to each
>     other). In a `for` loop you could have two indices: `source` and
>     `destination`. (On each loop you copy `source` to `destination` unless they
>     are the same, and increment both by 1). Every time you find a
>     duplicate you increment source (and don't perform the copy).
>     @morgano

Comment: Any examples that you can include?

Comment: @Lion check the code here - https://gist.github.com/anil477/c2349420b7ebca121ef82ca30b771bcd

Answer (score 45):

you can take the help of **Set** collection

```
int end = arr.length;
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();

for(int i = 0; i < end; i++){
  set.add(arr[i]);
}
```

now if you will iterate through this **set**, it will contain only unique values. Iterating code is like this :

```
Iterator it = set.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
  System.out.println(it.next());
}
```

Comment: I'm supposed to write my own implementation for this exercise. But thanks anyway.

Comment: OP clearly says he wants to solve without Set. Please read the question before answering.

Comment: I Came here to search for a method which is easy and understandable, for me it doesn't matter whether it's set or anything. Thank you so much for this great help

Comment: @goyalshub1509, when I answered it was not written that he wants without set, so I answered like that.

Comment: But question itself says dont use SET collection, then why this answer here?

Comment: @AngadBansode read my answer prior to your comment please.

Answer (score 33):

If you are allowed to use Java 8 streams:

```
Arrays.stream(arr).distinct().toArray();
```

Answer (score 19):

**Note: I am assuming the array is sorted.**

Code:

```
int[] input = new int[]{1, 1, 3, 7, 7, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10};
int current = input[0];
boolean found = false;

for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (current == input[i] && !found) {
        found = true;
    } else if (current != input[i]) {
        System.out.print(" " + current);
        current = input[i];
        found = false;
    }
}
System.out.print(" " + current);
```

output:

```
  1 3 7 8 9 10
```

Comment: you are assuming the array is sorted so it will fail if the array has duplicates at random places or is unsorted.

Comment: @kick Butowski well if array is sorted it can be done much simpler with XOR operation .see mine answer

Comment: assumes array is sorted

Comment: Nice algorithm to remove duplicate elements for the sorted array.

Answer (score 13):

Slight modification to the original code itself, by removing the innermost for loop.

```
public static int[] removeDuplicates(int[] arr){
    int end = arr.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < end; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < end; j++) {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {                  
                /*int shiftLeft = j;
                for (int k = j+1; k < end; k++, shiftLeft++) {
                    arr[shiftLeft] = arr[k];
                }*/
                arr[j] = arr[end-1];
                end--;
                j--;
            }
        }
    }

    int[] whitelist = new int[end];
    /*for(int i = 0; i < end; i++){
        whitelist[i] = arr[i];
    }*/
    System.arraycopy(arr, 0, whitelist, 0, end);
    return whitelist;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Since you can assume the range is between 0-1000 there is a very simple and efficient solution

```
//Throws an exception if values are not in the range of 0-1000
public static int[] removeDuplicates(int[] arr) {
    boolean[] set = new boolean[1001]; //values must default to false
    int totalItems = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        if (!set[arr[i]]) {
            set[arr[i]] = true;
            totalItems++;
        }
    }

    int[] ret = new int[totalItems];
    int c = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < set.length; ++i) {
        if (set[i]) {
            ret[c++] = i;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

This runs in linear time O(n). Caveat: the returned array is sorted so if that is illegal then this answer is invalid.

Comment: Your implementation is similar to Bucket Sort algorithm.

Comment: `== false` and `== true`? Ever heard of `!` ?

Comment: Why == true? facepalm

Comment: why we are creating new array with totalItems, we can save memory using same array, below is code:
 int c = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
         if (set[arr[i]]) {
          arr[c++] = arr[i];
          System.out.println(arr[i]);
             set[arr[i]] = false;
         }
     }

Answer (score 8):

There exists many solution of this problem.

1. The sort approach

   - You sort your array and resolve only unique items
2. The set approach

   - You declare a HashSet where you put all item then you have only unique ones.
3. You create a boolean array that represent the items all ready returned, (this depend on your data in the array).

If you deal with large amount of data i would pick the 1. solution. As you do not allocate additional memory and sorting is quite fast. For small set of data the complexity would be n^2 but for large i will be n log n.

Answer (score 8):

```
class Demo 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int a[]={3,2,1,4,2,1};
        System.out.print("Before Sorting:");
        for (int i=0;i<a.length; i++ )
        {
            System.out.print(a[i]+"\t");
        }
        System.out.print ("\nAfter Sorting:");
        //sorting the elements
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=i;j<a.length;j++)
            {
                if(a[i]>a[j])
                {
                    int temp=a[i];
                    a[i]=a[j];
                    a[j]=temp;
                }

            }
        }

        //After sorting
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(a[i]+"\t");
        }
        System.out.print("\nAfter removing duplicates:");
        int b=0;
        a[b]=a[0];
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        {
            if (a[b]!=a[i])
            {
                b++;
                a[b]=a[i];
            }
        }
        for (int i=0;i<=b;i++ )
        {
            System.out.print(a[i]+"\t");
        }
    }
}
  OUTPUT:Before Sortng:3 2 1 4 2 1 After Sorting:1 1 2 2 3 4 
                Removing Duplicates:1 2 3 4
```

Comment: Answers like these are much more helpful to the community if you explain a bit about what you've done.

Comment: Efficient removal of duplicates but not efficient sorting :-)

Answer (score 5):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Practice {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a[] = { 1, 3, 3, 4, 2, 1, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 10 };
    Arrays.sort(a);
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
        if (a[i] != a[i + 1]) {
            a[j] = a[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    a[j] = a[a.length - 1];
    for (int i = 0; i <= j; i++) {
        System.out.println(a[i]);
    }

}
}
**This is the most simplest way**
```

Answer (score 4):

What if you create two boolean arrays: 1 for negative values and 1 for positive values and init it all on false.

Then you cycle thorugh the input array and lookup in the arrays if you've encoutered the value already.
If not, you add it to the output array and mark it as already used.

Comment: I think this is the best approach... I would also try to use a biginteger instead of array of boolean (It is more efficient in memory use, but It is a little hard to understand because you will need to do bitwise operations)

Answer (score 4):

```
package com.pari.practice;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;

import com.pari.sort.Sort;

public class RemoveDuplicates {

 /**
 * brute force- o(N square)
 * 
 * @param input
 * @return
 */
public static int[] removeDups(int[] input){
    boolean[] isSame = new boolean[input.length];
    int sameNums = 0;

    for( int i = 0; i < input.length; i++ ){
        for( int j = i+1; j < input.length; j++){
            if( input[j] == input[i] ){ //compare same
                isSame[j] = true;
                sameNums++;
            }
        }
    }

    //compact the array into the result.
    int[] result = new int[input.length-sameNums];
    int count = 0;
    for( int i = 0; i < input.length; i++ ){
        if( isSame[i] == true) {
            continue;
        }
        else{
            result[count] = input[i];
            count++;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

/**
 * set - o(N)
 * does not guarantee order of elements returned - set property
 * 
 * @param input
 * @return
 */
public static int[] removeDups1(int[] input){
    HashSet myset = new HashSet();

    for( int i = 0; i < input.length; i++ ){
        myset.add(input[i]);
    }

    //compact the array into the result.
    int[] result = new int[myset.size()];
    Iterator setitr = myset.iterator();
    int count = 0;
    while( setitr.hasNext() ){
        result[count] = (int) setitr.next();
        count++;
    }

return result;
}

/**
 * quicksort - o(Nlogn)
 * 
 * @param input
 * @return
 */
public static int[] removeDups2(int[] input){
    Sort st = new Sort();
    st.quickSort(input, 0, input.length-1); //input is sorted

    //compact the array into the result.
    int[] intermediateResult = new int[input.length];
    int count = 0;
    int prev = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for( int i = 0; i < input.length; i++ ){
        if( input[i] != prev ){
            intermediateResult[count] = input[i];
            count++;
        }
        prev = input[i];
    }

    int[] result = new int[count];
    System.arraycopy(intermediateResult, 0, result, 0, count);

    return result;
}


public static void printArray(int[] input){
    for( int i = 0; i < input.length; i++ ){
        System.out.print(input[i] + " ");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] input = {5,6,8,0,1,2,5,9,11,0};
    RemoveDuplicates.printArray(RemoveDuplicates.removeDups(input));
    System.out.println();
    RemoveDuplicates.printArray(RemoveDuplicates.removeDups1(input));
    System.out.println();
    RemoveDuplicates.printArray(RemoveDuplicates.removeDups2(input));
}
}
```

Output:
5 6 8 0 1 2 9 11

0 1 2 5 6 8 9 11

0 1 2 5 6 8 9 11

I have just written the above code for trying out. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static int[] removeDuplicates(int[] arr){
    HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
    final int len = arr.length;
    //changed end to len
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        set.add(arr[i]);
    }

    int[] whitelist = new int[set.size()];
    int i = 0;
    for (Iterator<Integer> it = set.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        whitelist[i++] = it.next();
    }
    return whitelist;
}
```

Runs in O(N) time instead of your O(N^3) time

Comment: I guess this won't maintain the order of the array. You'd better use a Set-Implementation which does so.

Answer (score 3):

Not a big fun of updating user input, however considering your constraints...

```
public int[] removeDup(int[] nums) {
  Arrays.sort(nums);
  int x = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    if (i == 0 || nums[i] != nums[i - 1]) {
    nums[x++] = nums[i];
    }
  }
  return Arrays.copyOf(nums, x);
}
```

Array sort can be easily replaced with any nlog(n) algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

For a sorted Array, just check the next index:

```
//sorted data!
public static int[] distinct(int[] arr) {
    int[] temp = new int[arr.length];

    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        int current = arr[i];

        if(count > 0 )
            if(temp[count - 1] == current)
                continue;

        temp[count] = current;
        count++;
    }

    int[] whitelist = new int[count];
    System.arraycopy(temp, 0, whitelist, 0, count);

    return whitelist;
}
```

Comment: The code as it stands won't work because `new int[] {};` is an empty array so you will get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. More damming perhaps is that binary search only works on **sorted data**. You have not sorted the data. And once the data is sorted then the binary search is redundant.

Comment: So other that u cant read, everything's ok? there is a note on the bottom of my answer(so basically u cant read?) + the comment from ashur states that the array can be sorted...so this is spam?

Comment: ps sorted data = unique data? in what universe? the only other option would be to check the index+1 item and that is the only part of your comment that has any sense

Comment: Sorry, I guess I misunderstood. I think you need to set the value `int[]` to `new int[arr.lenght]` as otherwise the code won't work. And you need to add that the array must be **already** sorted. All the OP said was that you _can_ sort the data not that it is already sorted. I still don't think this answer is correct. And as for sort == unqiue, that is not what I said. All I said was that if the data is sorted then you can find unique values without binary search as they are, by definition, adjacent - you therefore don't need to go looking for them.

Comment: yeah your right on the binary search part, but either way the data needs to be sorted...so an index+1 would be the best idea

Comment: So, if the array is **already** sorted then your method is over complicated and you can collapse adjacent values. If the data is **not yet sorted** then your method does not work...

Comment: i didn't suggest this for my method, i suggested it for the index+1 part, wait ill edit the answer

Comment: It's simple. There is no set of circumstances under which the code makes sense. There are two scenarios, lets call them **A** and **B**. In scenario **A** is array is passed in **sorted**. In scenario **B** the array is passed in **unsorted**. So, in **A** your code will work but it doesn't makes sense; you can more easily collapse on adjacent values. In scenario **B** your code will **not** work, you must sort the array first; in that case see **A**.

Comment: In your new method you return an array with loads of zeroes at the end. You should really compact the array otherwise it will be impossible to use... Your first method is still doesn't make sense so I would delete it.

Comment: I Don't agree with @mc_fish as i wont assume a sorted array.

Answer (score 2):

This is simple way to sort the elements in the array

```
public class DublicatesRemove {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("enter size of the array");
        int l = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        int[] a = new int[l];
        // insert elements in the array logic
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) 
        {
            System.out.println("enter a element");
            int el = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            a[i] = el;
        }
        // sorting elements in the array logic
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < l - 1; j++) 
            {
                if (a[j] > a[j + 1])
                {
                    int temp = a[j];
                    a[j] = a[j + 1];
                    a[j + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        // remove duplicate elements logic
        int b = 0;
        a[b] = a[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < l; i++)
        {
            if (a[b] != a[i])
            {
                b++;
                a[b]=a[i];

            }

        }
        for(int i=0;i<=b;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(a[i]);
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so you cannot use `Set` or other collections.  One solution I don't see here so far is one based on the use of a [Bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter), which essentially is an array of bits, so perhaps that passes your requirements.

The Bloom filter is a lovely and very handy technique, fast and space-efficient, that can be used to do a quick check of the existence of an element in a set without storing the set itself or the elements.  It has a (typically small) false positive rate, but no false negative rate.  In other words, for your question, if a Bloom filter tells you that an element hasn't been seen so far, you can be sure it hasn't.  But if it says that an element has been seen, you actually need to check.  This still saves a lot of time if there aren't too many duplicates in your list (for those, there is no looping to do, except in the small probability case of a false positive --you typically chose this rate based on how much space you are willing to give to the Bloom filter (rule of thumb: less than 10 bits per unique element for a false positive rate of 1%).

There are many implementations of Bloom filters, see e.g. [here](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/collections/bloom_filter_java.shtml) or [here](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/hash/BloomFilter.html), so I won't repeat that in this answer.  Let us just assume the api described in that last reference, in particular, the [description](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/hash/BloomFilter.html#put-T-) of `put(E e)`:

> `true` if the Bloom filter's bits changed as a result of this operation. If the bits changed, this is *definitely* the first time object has been added to the filter. If the bits haven't changed, this *might* be the first time object has been added to the filter. (...)

An implementation using such a Bloom filter would then be:

```
public static int[] removeDuplicates(int[] arr) {
    ArrayList<Integer> out = new ArrayList<>();
    int n = arr.length;
    BloomFilter<Integer> bf = new BloomFilter<>(...);  // decide how many bits and how many hash functions to use (compromise between space and false positive rate)

    for (int e : arr) {
        boolean might_contain = !bf.put(e);
        boolean found = false;
        if (might_contain) {
            // check if false positive
            for (int u : out) {
                if (u == e) {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            out.add(e);
        }
    }
    return out.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();
}
```

Obviously, if you can alter the incoming array in place, then there is no need for an `ArrayList`: at the end, when you know the actual number of unique elements, just `arraycopy()` those.

Answer (score 1):

You need to sort your array then then loop and remove duplicates. As you cannot use other tools you need to write be code yourself.

You can easily find examples of quicksort in Java [on the internet](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaAlgorithmsQuicksort/article.html) (on which this example is based).

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final int[] original = new int[]{1, 1, 2, 8, 9, 8, 4, 7, 4, 9, 1};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(original));
    quicksort(original);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(original));
    final int[] unqiue = new int[original.length];
    int prev = original[0];
    unqiue[0] = prev;
    int count = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < original.length; ++i) {
        if (original[i] != prev) {
            unqiue[count++] = original[i];
        }
        prev = original[i];
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(unqiue));
    final int[] compressed = new int[count];
    System.arraycopy(unqiue, 0, compressed, 0, count);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(compressed));
}

private static void quicksort(final int[] values) {
    if (values.length == 0) {
        return;
    }
    quicksort(values, 0, values.length - 1);
}

private static void quicksort(final int[] values, final int low, final int high) {
    int i = low, j = high;
    int pivot = values[low + (high - low) / 2];
    while (i <= j) {
        while (values[i] < pivot) {
            i++;
        }
        while (values[j] > pivot) {
            j--;
        }
        if (i <= j) {
            swap(values, i, j);
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    if (low < j) {
        quicksort(values, low, j);
    }
    if (i < high) {
        quicksort(values, i, high);
    }
}

private static void swap(final int[] values, final int i, final int j) {
    final int temp = values[i];
    values[i] = values[j];
    values[j] = temp;
}
```

So the process runs in 3 steps.

1. Sort the array  - `O(nlgn)`
2. Remove duplicates - `O(n)`
3. Compact the array - `O(n)`

So this improves significantly on your `O(n^3)` approach.

Output:

```
[1, 1, 2, 8, 9, 8, 4, 7, 4, 9, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9]
[1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 9]
```

**EDIT**

OP states *values inside array doesn't matter really. But I can assume that range is between 0-1000*. This is a classic case where an O(n) sort can be used.

We create an array of size `range +1`, in this case `1001`. We then loop over the data and increment the values on each index corresponding to the datapoint.

We can then compact the resulting array, dropping values the have not been incremented. This makes the values unique as we ignore the count.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final int[] original = new int[]{1, 1, 2, 8, 9, 8, 4, 7, 4, 9, 1, 1000, 1000};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(original));
    final int[] buckets = new int[1001];
    for (final int i : original) {
        buckets[i]++;
    }
    final int[] unique = new int[original.length];
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < buckets.length; ++i) {
        if (buckets[i] > 0) {
            unique[count++] = i;
        }
    }
    final int[] compressed = new int[count];
    System.arraycopy(unique, 0, compressed, 0, count);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(compressed));
}
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 2, 8, 9, 8, 4, 7, 4, 9, 1, 1000, 1000]
[1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 9, 1000]
```

Comment: bad idea... why find the max value? u need to go through all values? like i said in my comment earlier, sort it and check for the index+1 item

Comment: @mc_fish The OP states the range of the values. That's why I suggested two approaches. One if the range is unknown and one if the range is **known** and **small**.

Comment: yeah but he run a test at 1M? just saying

Comment: Yes, 1M values but, to quote his comment, _assume that range is between 0-1000_. So the range is very small.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[] intarray = {1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5};

    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
    for(int i : intarray) {
        set.add(i);
    }

    Iterator<Integer> setitr = set.iterator();
    for(int pos=0; pos < intarray.length; pos ++) {
        if(pos < set.size()) {
            intarray[pos] =setitr.next();
        } else {
            intarray[pos]= 0;
        }
    }

    for(int i: intarray)
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: The output of this program is : 1
2
3
4
5
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0

Answer (score 1):

I know this is kinda dead but I just wrote this for my own use. It's more or less the same as adding to a hashset and then pulling all the elements out of it. It should run in O(nlogn) worst case.

```
    public static int[] removeDuplicates(int[] numbers) {
    Entry[] entries = new Entry[numbers.length];
    int size = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < numbers.length ; i++) {
        int nextVal = numbers[i];
        int index = nextVal % entries.length;
        Entry e = entries[index];
        if (e == null) {
            entries[index] = new Entry(nextVal);
            size++;
        } else {
            if(e.insert(nextVal)) {
                size++;
            }
        }
    }
    int[] result = new int[size];
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < entries.length ; i++) {
        Entry current = entries[i];
        while (current != null) {
            result[i++] = current.value;
            current = current.next;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

public static class Entry {
    int value;
    Entry next;

    Entry(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public boolean insert(int newVal) {
        Entry current = this;
        Entry prev = null;
        while (current != null) {
            if (current.value == newVal) {
                return false;
            } else if(current.next != null) {
                prev = current;
                current = next;
            }
        }
        prev.next = new Entry(value);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int tempvar=0; //Variable for the final array without any duplicates
     int whilecount=0;    //variable for while loop
     while(whilecount<(nsprtable*2)-1) //nsprtable can be any number
     {
//to check whether the next value is idential in case of sorted array       
if(temparray[whilecount]!=temparray[whilecount+1])
        {
            finalarray[tempvar]=temparray[whilecount];
            tempvar++;
            whilecount=whilecount+1;
        }
        else if (temparray[whilecount]==temparray[whilecount+1])
        {
            finalarray[tempvar]=temparray[whilecount];
            tempvar++;
            whilecount=whilecount+2;
        }
     }
```

Hope this helps or solves the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

How about this one, only for **the sorted Array** of numbers, to print the Array without duplicates, **without using Set** or other Collections, just an Array:

```
 public static int[] removeDuplicates(int[] array) {
    int[] nums = new int[array.length];
    int addedNumber = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for(int i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (addedNumber != array[i]) {
        nums[j] = array[i];
        j++;
        addedNumber = nums[j-1];
        }
    }
    return Arrays.copyOf(nums, j);
}
```

An array of 1040 duplicated numbers processed in 33020 nanoseconds(**0.033020 millisec**).

Comment: Excellent solution except for one small change. Please move array.length outside of for loop.

Comment: This is Quite optimized

Answer (score 1):

```
 package javaa;

public class UniqueElementinAnArray 
{

 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
    int[] a = {10,10,10,10,10,100};
    int[] output = new int[a.length];
    int count = 0;
    int num = 0;

    //Iterate over an array
    for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    {
        num=a[i];
        boolean flag = check(output,num);
        if(flag==false)
        {
            output[count]=num;
            ++count;
        }

    }

    //print the all the elements from an array except zero's (0)
    for (int i : output) 
    {
        if(i!=0 )
            System.out.print(i+"  ");
    }

}

/***
 * If a next number from an array is already exists in unique array then return true else false
 * @param arr   Unique number array. Initially this array is an empty.
 * @param num   Number to be search in unique array. Whether it is duplicate or unique.
 * @return  true: If a number is already exists in an array else false 
 */
public static boolean check(int[] arr, int num)
{
    boolean flag = false;
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i]==num)
        {
            flag = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

This is an interview question.

```
public class Test4 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
     int a[] = {1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 6,6,6,6,6,66,7,65}; 
              int newlength =    lengthofarraywithoutduplicates(a);
              for(int i = 0 ; i < newlength ;i++) {
                  System.out.println(a[i]);
              }//for
}//main

private static int lengthofarraywithoutduplicates(int[] a) {
     int count = 1 ;
     for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
          int ch = a[i];
          if(ch != a[i-1]) {
              a[count++] = ch;
          }//if
    }//for
    return count;
    
}//fix

}//end1
```

But, it's always better to use Stream :

```
int[] a = {1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 6,6,6,6,6,66,7,65};
int[] array = Arrays.stream(a).distinct().toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));//[1, 2, 3, 6, 66, 7, 65]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int[] removeDuplicates(int[] arr) {

int end = arr.length;

 HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>(end);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < end ; i++){
        set.add(arr[i]);
    }
return set.toArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an auxiliary array (temp) which in indexes are numbers of main array. So the time complexity will be liner and O(n). As we want to do it without using any library, we define another array (unique) to push non-duplicate elements:

```js
var num = [2,4,9,4,1,2,24,12,4];
let temp = [];
let unique = [];
let j = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < num.length; i++){
  if (temp[num[i]] !== 1){
    temp[num[i]] = 1;
    unique[j++] = num[i];
  }
}
console.log(unique);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to remove duplicates using the same array and also keeping the time complexity of O(n). Then this should do the trick. Also, would only work if the array is sorted.

```
function removeDuplicates_sorted(arr){

let j = 0; 

for(let x = 0; x < arr.length - 1; x++){
    
    if(arr[x] != arr[x + 1]){ 
        arr[j++] = arr[x];
    }
}

arr[j++] = arr[arr.length - 1];
arr.length = j;

return arr;
```

}

Here is for an unsorted array, its O(n) but uses more space complexity then the sorted.

```
function removeDuplicates_unsorted(arr){

let map = {};
let j = 0;

for(var numbers of arr){
    if(!map[numbers]){
        map[numbers] = 1;
        arr[j++] = numbers;
    }
}

arr.length = j;

return arr;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Note to other readers who desire to use the Set method of solving this problem: If original ordering must be preserved, do not use HashSet as in the top result. HashSet does not guarantee the preservation of the original order, so LinkedHashSet should be used instead-this keeps track of the order in which the elements were inserted into the set and returns them in that order.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] intArray = { 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 5, 3, 6, 7, 3, 4, 5 };
        Integer[] finalArray = removeDuplicates(intArray);
        System.err.println(Arrays.asList(finalArray));
    }

    private static Integer[] removeDuplicates(Integer[] intArray) {
        int count = 0;
        Integer[] interimArray = new Integer[intArray.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
            boolean exists = false;
            for (int j = 0; j < interimArray.length; j++) {
                if (interimArray[j]!=null && interimArray[j] == intArray[i]) {
                    exists = true;
                }
            }
            if (!exists) {
                interimArray[count] = intArray[i];
                count++;
            }
        }
        final Integer[] finalArray = new Integer[count];
        System.arraycopy(interimArray, 0, finalArray, 0, count);
        return finalArray;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel Android Killer's idea is great, but I just wondered if we can leverage HashMap. So I did a little experiment. And I found HashMap seems faster than HashSet.

Here is code:

```
    int[] input = new int[1000000];

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        Random random = new Random();
        input[i] = random.nextInt(200000);
    }

    long startTime1 = new Date().getTime();
    System.out.println("Set start time:" + startTime1);

    Set<Integer> resultSet = new HashSet<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        resultSet.add(input[i]);
    }

    long endTime1 = new Date().getTime();
    System.out.println("Set end time:"+ endTime1);
    System.out.println("result of set:" + (endTime1 - startTime1));     
    System.out.println("number of Set:" + resultSet.size() + "\n");

    long startTime2 = new Date().getTime();
    System.out.println("Map start time:" + startTime1);

    Map<Integer, Integer> resultMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if (!resultMap.containsKey(input[i]))
            resultMap.put(input[i], input[i]);
    }

    long endTime2 = new Date().getTime();
    System.out.println("Map end Time:" + endTime2);
    System.out.println("result of Map:" + (endTime2 - startTime2));
    System.out.println("number of Map:" + resultMap.size());
```

Here is result:

```
Set start time:1441960583837
Set end time:1441960583917
result of set:80
number of Set:198652

Map start time:1441960583837
Map end Time:1441960583983
result of Map:66
number of Map:198652
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not using Set, Map, List or any extra collection, only two arrays:

```
package arrays.duplicates;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ArrayDuplicatesRemover<T> {

    public static <T> T[] removeDuplicates(T[] input, Class<T> clazz) {
        T[] output = (T[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, 0);
        for (T t : input) {
            if (!inArray(t, output)) {
                output = Arrays.copyOf(output, output.length + 1);
                output[output.length - 1] = t;
            }
        }
        return output;
    }

    private static <T> boolean inArray(T search, T[] array) {
        for (T element : array) {
            if (element.equals(search)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

And the main to test it

```
package arrays.duplicates;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class TestArrayDuplicates {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] array = {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4};
        testArrayDuplicatesRemover(array);
    }

    private static void testArrayDuplicatesRemover(Integer[] array) {
        final Integer[] expectedResult = {1, 2, 3, 4};
        Integer[] arrayWithoutDuplicates = ArrayDuplicatesRemover.removeDuplicates(array, Integer.class);
        System.out.println("Array without duplicates is supposed to be: " + Arrays.toString(expectedResult));
        System.out.println("Array without duplicates currently is: " + Arrays.toString(arrayWithoutDuplicates));
        System.out.println("Is test passed ok?: " + (Arrays.equals(arrayWithoutDuplicates, expectedResult) ? "YES" : "NO"));
    }

}
```

And the output:

```
Array without duplicates is supposed to be: [1, 2, 3, 4]
Array without duplicates currently is: [1, 2, 3, 4]
Is test passed ok?: YES
```

Answer (score 0):

**Why do all people not check this below lines?**

*I need to write my own implementation - not to use Set, HashSet etc. Or any other tools such as iterators. Simply an array to remove duplicates.*

I'm posting very simple implementation with caring the above line.

```
public class RemoveDuplicates {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1 }; // input array
    int len = arr.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < len; j++) {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
                while (j < (len) - 1) {
                    arr[j] = arr[j - 1];
                    j++;
                }
                len--;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        System.out.print("  " +arr[i]);
    }

   }
 }
```

> Input  : 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1
>
> Output :   1  2  3  4

Comment: your solution is O(n^2) and this can improved further as someone here already mentioned in the comments. If you use quick sort then the average case complexity is O(nlogn) (merge sort also works) to sort the array. and next you can go over the sorted array once to replace all duplicates in O(n).  so the over all complexity is O(nlogn).

Comment: I have answered according to question

Comment: Wrong program try this  : --      int[] arr = {1,2,3,4,2,3,1,1,11,6,1}; // input array 1  2  3  4  4  4 //output

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. The time complexity is o(n^2)

```
public String removeDuplicates(char[] arr) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        if (arr == null)
            return null;
        int len = arr.length;

        if (arr.length < 2)
            return sb.append(arr[0]).toString();

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {

            for (int j = i + 1; j < len; j++) {
                if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
                    arr[j] = 0;

                }
            }
            if (arr[i] != 0)
                sb.append(arr[i]);
        }

        return sb.toString().trim();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void removeDup(){ 
String[] arr = {"1","1","2","3","3"};
          boolean exists = false;
          String[] arr2 = new String[arr.length];
          int count1 = 0;
          for(int loop=0;loop<arr.length;loop++)
            {
              String val = arr[loop];
              exists = false;
              for(int loop2=0;loop2<arr2.length;loop2++)
              {     
                  if(arr2[loop2]==null)break;
                  if(arr2[loop2]==val){
                        exists = true;
                }
              }
              if(!exists) {
                    arr2[count1] = val;
                    count1++;
              }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres a simpler, better way to do this using arraylists instead:

```
public static final <T> ArrayList<T> removeDuplicates(ArrayList<T> in){
    ArrayList<T> out = new ArrayList<T>();
    for(T t : in) 
        if(!out.contains(t)) 
            out.add(t);
    return out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to remove duplicates from integer array without using set is, just create a temp array and iterate the original array and check if number exists in temp array then do not push into array else put into temp array and return temp array as result. Please consider the following code snippet :

```
package com.numbers;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class RemoveDuplicates {
    public int[] removeDuplicate(int[] array) {
        int[] tempArray = new int[array.length];
        int j = 0;
        for (int i : array) {
            if (!isExists(tempArray, i)) {
                tempArray[j++] = i;
            }
        }
        return tempArray;
    }

    public static boolean isExists(int[] array, int num) {
        if (array == null)
            return false;
        for (int i : array) {
            if (i == num) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] array = { 10, 20, 30, 10, 45, 30 };
        RemoveDuplicates duplicates = new RemoveDuplicates();
        System.out.println("Before removing duplicates : " + Arrays.toString(array));
        int [] newArray = duplicates.removeDuplicate(array);
        System.out.println("After removing duplicates : " + Arrays.toString(newArray));

    }
}
```

Comment: in the `removeDuplicate` at the very end the last line before `return tempArray` you need something like `tempArray = Arrays.copyOf(tempArray,  j);` otherwise the initiated tempArray will be the size of original array which in short contains a bunch of 0's for all the entries that were in effect duplicates

Answer (score 0):

Just a trick to remove duplicates.

```
public class RemoveDuplicates {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {2,2,2,2,2,5,9, 4,5,6,1,6,6,2,4,7};
        arr = removeDuplicates(arr);    
        print(arr);
    }

    public static int[] removeDuplicates(int [] arr) {
        final int garbage = -2147483648;
        int duplicates = 0;

        for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            for(int j=i+1; j<arr.length; j++) {
                if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
                    arr[i] = garbage;
                    duplicates++;
                }
            }
        }

        int[] nArr = new int[arr.length - duplicates];
        int nItr = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] != garbage) {
                nArr[nItr] = arr[i];
                nItr++;
            } 
        }
        return nArr;
    }

    public static void print(int [] arr) {
        for (int n : arr) {
            System.out.print(n + "\t");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can remove duplicates using heap data structure.

1. Create a min Heap or Max heap [I use min Heap](Takes `O(n)`)
2. remove the elements from the heap and store it into another list if that element is not in that list. This  takes `O(nlog(n))` since we remove an element from the heap and it takes `log n` we do this  until the all n elements removed from the heap `n * logn`

Overall Time complexity is `O(nlog(n))`.

Python code for my approach

```
import heapq

l =[1,2,4,6,3,2,6,1]

heapq.heapify(l)
no_duplicate_list =[]

try:
    while True:
        e = heapq.heappop(l)# will return the minimum value from the heap 
        if no_duplicate_list ==[]:
            no_duplicate_list.append(e)
        else:
            if e == no_duplicate_list[-1]:
                continue
            no_duplicate_list.append(e)
except IndexError as i:
    print(no_duplicate_list) #[1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = new int[]{1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2};
    int[] newArray  = removeDuplicates(array);
    for (int i : newArray) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}

// the total time complexity is O(n^2)
public static int[] removeDuplicates(int[] arr) {
    int[] newArr = new int[arr.length];    //O(n)
    int count = 0;

   for (int i : arr) {                     //O(n)
        boolean result = check(newArr, i); //O(n)

        if (result)
            newArr[count++] = i;
    }
    return  Arrays.copyOf(newArr, count);  //O(n)
}

public static boolean check(int[] arr, int value){
    boolean result = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(arr[i] == value){
            result = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in-place which will make the space complexity O(1). Time complexity will be O(n) like many other solutions.

```
public static int removeDuplicates(int[] nums) {
        // Sort un-sorted array
        Arrays.sort(nums);

        int n = nums.length;
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
            if (nums[i] != nums[i+1]) {
                nums[k++] = nums[i];
            }
        }
        nums[k++] = nums[n-1];

        return k;
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] nums = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 2, 1}; // your input array

        int k = removeDuplicates(nums);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            System.out.println(nums[i]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Well first answer will be to use hashset which is designed to remove duplicates as Android Killer answer pointed out

**Approach 2 :-**
But if you are not allowed to use set then sort it first with quicksort which will be nlogn and then apply `XOR` operation to find duplicates

Optimized one

```
public static void removeDuplicates(int[] arr) {
        int[] input = new int[] { 1, 1, 3, 7, 7, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10 };
        int current = input[0];
        boolean found = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length-1; i++) {

            if((input[i]^input[i+1])==0){
                System.out.println(input[i]);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried running this code? It does the opposite and prints 1 7 9 9. If you change == 0 to != 0 it will still miss 10.

Comment: @Andrey Actually i wrote it print the duplicate elements. We can tweak it to print index also . Then either make new except those indexes or make duplicates one null(change integer to Integer object) in existing array depending upon the

Comment: Maybe this doesn't answer the question very precisely, but it solved another problem I had.

Answer (score -1):

Please check this. It will work for both sorted/unsorted array. The complexity is O(n^2) same as bubble sort. 
Yes the complexity can be improved further with first sort and then binary search. But this is simple enough to work on every cases except negative element (-1). This can also be changed by using large integer value instead of -1.

```
void remove_duplicates(int *A, int N)

{

int i,j;

for (i=1; i<N; i++) {
    if (A[i] == -1) continue;
    for (j=i+1; j<=N; j++) {
        if (A[i] == A[j])
            A[j] = -1;
    }
}
}

int main() {

int N;
int A[1001];
int i;

printf("Enter N: ");
scanf("%d", &N);
printf("Enter the elements:\n");
for (i=1; i<=N; i++)
    scanf("%d", &A[i]);

remove_duplicates(A, N);
for (i=1; i<=N; i++) {
    if (A[i] == -1)
        continue;
    printf("%d  ", A[i]);
}
printf("\n");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.  It isn't Java,

Answer (score -2):

```
public class RemoveDuplicates {
public Integer[] returnUniqueNumbers(Integer[] original,
        Integer[] uniqueNumbers) {
    int k = 0;  

    for (int j =  original.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        boolean present = false;
        for (Integer u : uniqueNumbers) {
            if (u != null){
            if(u.equals(original[j])) {
                present = true;
            }}
        }
        if (present == false) {
            uniqueNumbers[k] = original[j];
            k++;
        }
    }
    return uniqueNumbers;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    RemoveDuplicates removeDup = new RemoveDuplicates();
    Integer[] original = { 10, 20, 40, 30, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10, 50, 50, 50,20,30,10,40 };
    Integer[] finalValue = new Integer[original.length + 1];

    // method to return unique values
    Integer[] unique = removeDup.returnUniqueNumbers(original, finalValue);

    // iterate to return unique values
    for (Integer u : unique) {
        if (u != null) {
            System.out.println("unique value : " + u);
        }
    }
}}
```

This code handles unsorted array containing multiple duplicates for same value and returns unique elements.

Answer (score -2):

I have done using sample as 12 elements,

public class Remdup_arr {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int a[] = {1,1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,8,6,8};
    for(int p : a)
    {
        System.out.print(p);
        System.out.print("\t");
    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

    remdup(a);

}

private static void remdup(int[] a) {

    int length = a.length;
    int b[] = new int[11];
    int d = 1;
    b[0]=a[0];
    while(length<13 && length>0)
    {
        int x = a[length-1];
        if(!(contain(b , x)))
            {b[d] = a[length-1];
            d++;}
        length--;


    }

    for( int z = 0;z<b.length;z++){
        System.out.print(b[z]);
        System.out.print("\t");}

}

private static boolean contain(int[] b ,int p) {

    boolean bool = false;
    int len = b.length;
    for(int i = 0;i<len;i++)
    {
        if(p == b[i])
            bool = true;
    }



    return bool;

}
```

}

output is :-
1   1   2   3   4   4   5   6   7   8   6   8

1   8   6   7   5   4   3   2   0   0   0

Answer (score -2):

Use the ArrayUtil class as you need. I have written some methods other than removing duplicates. This class is implemented without using any Collection framework classes.

```
public class ArrayUtils {
/**
 * Removes all duplicate elements from an array. 
 * @param arr Array from which duplicate elements are to be removed.
 * @param removeAllDuplicates true if remove all duplicate values, false otherwise 
 * @return Array of unique elements.
 */
public static int[] removeDuplicate(int[] arr, boolean removeAllDuplicates)         {
    int size = arr.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < size;) {
        boolean flag = false;

        for (int j = i + 1; j < size;) {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
                flag = true;
                shrinkArray(arr, j, size);
                size--;
            } else
                j++;
        }

        if (flag && removeAllDuplicates) {
            shrinkArray(arr, i, size);
            size--;
        } else
            i++;
    }

    int unique[] = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        unique[i] = arr[i];

    return unique;
}

/**
 * Removes duplicate elements from an array. 
 * @param arr Array from which duplicate elements are to be removed.
 * @return Array of unique elements.
 */
public static int[] removeDuplicate(int[] arr) {
    return removeDuplicate(arr, false);
}


private static void shrinkArray(int[] arr, int pos, int size) {
    for (int i = pos; i < size - 1; i++) {
        arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
    }
}

/**
 * Displays the array.
 * @param arr The array to be displayed.
 */
public static void displayArray(int arr[]) {
    System.out.println("\n\nThe Array Is:-\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(arr[i] + "\t");
    }
}

/**
 * Initializes the array with a given value.
 * @param arr The array to be initialized.
 * @param withValue The value with which the array is to be initialized.
 */
public static void initializeArray(int[] arr, int withValue) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = withValue;
    }
}

/**
 * Checks whether an element is there in the array. 
 * @param arr The array in which the element is to be found.
 * @param element The element that is to be found.
 * @return True if found false otherwise
 */
public static boolean contains(int arr[], int element) {
    for(int i=0; i< arr.length; i++) {
        if(arr[i] == element)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

/**
 * Removes a element from an array.
 * @param arr The array from which the element is to removed.
 * @param element The element to be removed
 * @return The size of the array after removing.
 */
public static int removeElement(int[] arr, int element) {
    int size = arr.length;
    for(int i=0; i< arr.length; i++){
        if(arr[i] == element){
            shrinkArray(arr, i, arr.length);
            size--;
        }
    }
    return size;
}

/**
 * Counts unique elements in an array.
 * @param arr The required array.
 * @return Unique element count.
 */
public static int uniqueElementCount(int arr[]) {
    int count = 0;
    int uniqueCount=0;
    int[] consideredElements = new int[arr.length];

    initializeArray(consideredElements, 0);

    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
        int element = arr[i];
        for(int j=i+1;j<arr.length; j++){
            if(element != arr[j] && !contains(consideredElements, element)){
                consideredElements[count++] = element;
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i< consideredElements.length;i++)
        if(consideredElements[i]!=0)
            uniqueCount++;

    return uniqueCount;
}
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Hope it helps...

```
if (!checked)//Condition to add into array {
        $scope.selectWeekDays.push(WeekKeys);
    } else {
        for (i = 0; i <= $scope.selectWeekDays.length; i++) // Loop to check IsExists {
            if ($scope.selectWeekDays[i] == WeekKeys)//then if Equals removing by splice {
                $scope.selectWeekDays.splice(i, 1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
public class RemoveDuplicates {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int size;
        System.out.println("Enter an array size");
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        size = sc.nextInt();

        int arr[] = new int[size];

        System.out.println("Enter "+size+" numbers");
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
            arr[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }

        for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
            int count=0;
            for(int j=i+1;j<size;j++){
                if(arr[i]==arr[j]){

                    int shiftLeft = j;

                    for (int k = j+1; k < size; k++, shiftLeft++) {
                        arr[shiftLeft] = arr[k];
                    }
                    size--;
                    j--;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("New Array");
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
//Remove duplicate from sorted array

public class RemDupFromArray {
    static int num;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int arr[] = {0,0,2,2,3, 5, 5,7, 7, 7};
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length-1;i++){
            if(num!=arr[i]){
                num=arr[i];
                System.out.print(arr[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Note that this will only work if the array is sorted

Answer (score -2):

```
    public static int[] removeDuplicates(int[] input){

        int j = 0;
        int i = 1;
        //return if the array length is less than 2
        if(input.length < 2){
            return input;
        }
        while(i < input.length){
            if(input[i] == input[j]){
                i++;
            }else{
                j = j+1;
                input[j] = input[i];
                i = i+1;
            }    
        }
        int[] output = new int[j+1];
        for(int k=0; k<output.length; k++){
            output[k] = input[k];
        }

        return output;
    }

public static void main(String a[]){
        int[] input1 = {2,3,6,6,8,9,10,10,10,12,12};
        int[] output = removeDuplicates(input1);
        for(int i:output){
            System.out.println(i+" ");
        }
    }
```

Comment: If this code answers the question, consider adding adding some text explaining the code in your answer. This way, you are far more likely to get more upvotes — and help the questioner learn something new.

Answer (score -2):

```
import java.util.*;
class removeDuplicate{
int [] y ;

public removeDuplicate(int[] array){
    y=array;


    for(int b=0;b<y.length;b++){
        int temp = y[b];
        for(int v=0;v<y.length;v++){
            if( b!=v && temp==y[v]){
                y[v]=0;
            }
        }
    }




}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
  public static void main(String[] args) { 
            int input[] = { 1, 5, 1, 0, -3, 1, -3, 2, 1 }; 
            int j = 0; 
            int output[] = new int[100]; 
            Arrays.fill(a, 0); 
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) { 
                    if (output[input[i]] == 0) {
                            input[j++] = input[i]; 
                            output[input[i]]++; 
                    } 
            } 
            for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) { 
                    System.out.print(input[i] + " "); 
            } 
    }
```