# Java array and for loop causing wrong output

Tags: java, arrays

The requirements are to check for duplicate items in the array and delete it, the remaining items in the array must then shift to the left.

I wrote this:

```
public class TestRepeat {

public static int deleteRepeats(char[] ch) {

    int count = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < ch.length; x++) {
        for (int y = x + 1; y < ch.length; y++) {
            if (ch[x] == ch[y]) {
                for (int k = y; k < ch.length - 1; k++) {//shifts the array to the right if its a duplicate
                    ch[k] = ch[k + 1];
                }
                ch[ch.length - 1] = ' ';//replaces the last array with a blank
            }
        }
    }
    for (int q = 0; q < ch.length; q++) {
        if (ch[q] == ' ') {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;//returns the number of deleted items
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] ch = {'k', 'a', 'm', 'o', 'k', 'm', 'y', 'm', 'k', 'k', 'x', 'm', 'm', 'o'};
    System.out.print("The original array is: ");
    System.out.println(ch);
    System.out.println("Number of deleted characters: " + deleteRepeats(ch));
    System.out.print("The new array is: ");
    System.out.println(ch);
}

}
```

its supposed to return:

> The original array is: kamokmymkkxmmo
>
> Number of deleted characters: 8
>
> The new array is: kamoyx

but instead is returning:

> The original array is: kamokmymkkxmmo
>
> Number of deleted characters: 6
>
> The new array is: kamoykxm

What is causing the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17967114/59087

Comment: stackoverflow is not correct portal for this, please ask this on : http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @NoobEditor why is this not the correct portal?  He has a programming error which he does not know how to fix.

Answer (score 1):

I found two errors, one of which was causing your problem and the other was a corollary. First, you can't use a for loop for the inner loop because sometimes you are modifying the array you are looping over. Therefore on some iterations you are implicitly incrementing y twice: once by actually incrementing y, and again when you shift the part of array to the left. Thus, you should only actually be incrementing y when you don't perform a change on the array, and leave y where it is when you do delete an element. Second, you have to make sure you don't try to delete `' '`, because it will cause infinite recursion in the while loop version. The errors are fixed below:

```
public class TestRepeat {

/** Deletes index index in arr. Elements in (index, arr.length) are shifted to the left,
    And a ' ' is put at the end of arr 
    Precondition: index >= 0, index < arr.length */
private static void deleteAndShift(char[] arr, int index){
    for(int i = index; i < arr.length - 1; i++){
        arr[i] = arr[i+1];
    }
    arr[arr.length - 1] = ' ';
}

public static int deleteRepeats(char[] ch) {

    int count = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < ch.length; x++) {
        int y = x+1;
        while(y < ch.length){
            //Delete index y. Note that this 'implicitly' increments y by shifting ch.
            if (ch[x] != ' ' && ch[x] == ch[y]) {
               deleteAndShift(ch, y);
            }
            //Only increment y if an element wasn't deleted
            else{
              y++;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int q = 0; q < ch.length; q++) {
        if (ch[q] == ' ') {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;//returns the number of deleted items
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] ch = {'k', 'a', 'm', 'o', 'k', 'm', 'y', 'm', 'k', 'k', 'x', 'm', 'm', 'o'};
    System.out.print("The original array is: ");
    System.out.println(ch);
    System.out.println("Number of deleted characters: " + deleteRepeats(ch));
    System.out.print("The new array is: ");
    System.out.println(ch);
}

}
```

This code has your desired output of deleting 8 characters in the sample input.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `if` condition block `if (ch[x] == ch[y]) {` with,

```
if (ch[x] != ' ' && ch[x] == ch[y]) {                   
   for (int k = y; k < ch.length - 1; k++) {//shifts the array to the right if its a duplicate                      
       ch[k] = ch[k + 1];
   }                    
   ch[ch.length - 1] = ' ';//replaces the last array with a blank
   y--;
}
```

Comment: Altering the value of a for-loop index variable within the for loop isn't very good practice..

Comment: @Mshnik can alter if the control is fine, `y++` or `y--` in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

After you shift them to the left, do a y--;
This will help taking care of consecutive repeated elements

Answer (score 0):

With the help of [set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) we can easily implement it.

```
char[] ch = {'k', 'a', 'm', 'o', 'k', 'm', 'y', 'm', 'k', 'k', 'x', 'm', 'm', 'o'};
System.out.print("The original array is : ");
System.out.println(ch);

// Moving in to LinkedHashSet
Set<Character> charSet = new LinkedHashSet<Character>();
for(char c : ch) 
   charSet.add(c);

System.out.println("Number of deleted characters :"+(ch.length-charSet.size()));

// Move Back to newArray
char[] newch = new char[charSet.size()];
int i = 0;
for(char c : charSet)
   newch[i++] = c;

System.out.print("The new array is :");
System.out.println(newch);
```

Output:

```
The original array is : kamokmymkkxmmo
Number of deleted characters :8
The new array is :kamoyx
```