# Print sequence of numbers without consequtive duplicates?

Tags: java, arrays

Given a sequence of numbers like this:

```
1 2 2 5 5 5 1 7 3 7 7 7
```

Output should be

```
1 2 5 1 7 3 7
```

The current output of my code is

```
1 2 5 1 7 3
```

I am unable to fix the problem. Can anyone tell me what should I do or change in my code?

Here's my current code:

```
public class Q3 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int [] input=new int[]{1 ,2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 1, 7, 3, 7, 7, 7};
        int current= input[0];
        boolean found=false;
        for(int i=0; i< input.length; i++) {
             if(current == input[i] && !found) {
                found=true;
             } else if(current!=input[i]) {
                 System.out.print(" " + current);
                 current=input[i];
                 found=false;
             }
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you be more specific about the question.

Comment: Print the first occurrence and ignore the rest...

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera.  How does the question look after the edit done by MadProgrammer

Comment: anyone can believe this is my answer :D haha....

Comment: @MadProgrammer the op stole my answer how can I report it?

Comment: @KickButtowski don't know what you meant by your offensive comment, but this is stated in SO rules when you accept become a user of this site. Instead of taking this as *plagiarism*, be happy for someone in another part of the world using your code (with problems, but still yours).

Comment: @farhanakonka FYI- If you've picked up some from SO or even another resource which you can't get running, it's generally consider good manners to reference the source

Comment: @KickButtowski you can find the specific statement of this at the bottom of any page in the site, it is stated like this: *user contributions licensed under [cc by-sa 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) with [attribution required](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/)*

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza :) +1 for Unicorns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is not right to use other's answer without giving the credit**

```
int[] input = new int[]{1, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 1, 7, 3, 7, 7, 7};
int current = input[0];
boolean found = false;

for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (current == input[i] && !found) {
        found = true;
    } else if (current != input[i]) {
        System.out.print(" " + current);
        current = input[i];
        found = false;
    }
}
System.out.print(" " + current); <--- you forgot this line
```

output:

```
1 2 5 1 7 3 7
```

My answer can be found here 
[How to efficiently remove duplicates from an array without using Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17967114/how-to-remove-duplicates-from-an-array-in-java/25148131#25148131)

Comment: what is it ? have you ran my code to see what it does?

Comment: Read again. Input: **1 2 2 5 5 5 1 7 3 7 7 7**. Output: 1 2 5 **1** 7 3 **7**, I mark the *duplicate* elements that are part of the valid output.

Comment: dude run my code and see the result. the op stole my code and I know what it does

Comment: I don't need to run it to see if it will work. I was driven by the title of the other answer and the input/output sample of your code, not by your implementation. And now I could say you're right.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62384/discussion-between-kick-buttowski-and-luiggi-mendoza).

Answer (score 2):

The basic problem is, you need to seed the `current` value with something that is not equal to the first element, this way, you can just loop through the array without issues, flags or other tricks, for example...

```
int[] input = new int[]{1, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 1, 7, 3, 7, 7, 7};
int current = -input[0];

for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (current != input[i]) {
        current = input[i];
        System.out.print(" " + current);
    }
}
System.out.println("");
```

Which outputs...

```
1 2 5 1 7 3 7
```

This sets the `current` value to the negative of the first element (in this `-1`), so when we do our first comparison, `-1 != 1` and then we can proceeded as normal...

Comment: the op stole my answer how can I report this?

Comment: What do you mean by "stole?

Comment: go to the link and see that this is my answer

Comment: @KickButtowski You can't say OP **stole your answer** SO is open for all to learn something new and he/she just used your answer to learn.

Comment: @TAsk without mentioning me is the plagiarism in my country do not know about yorus

Comment: @KickButtowski If you do not want people to use your code, then why Post it on a public forum?  If the OP used your answer as he own answer and did not credit you, then that is a slightly different matter.

Comment: @KickButtowski The code you provide here is generally considered "open source", sure it would be nice if the OP had mentioned it, but it wouldn't be considered "stealing" - besides, the OP messed it up anyway ;)

Comment: @ScaryWombat this is the rule. if I use others code, I always put source.

Comment: @KickButtowski It's a common enough algorithm, no offense, have a look around all the answers, did anyone else plagiarize you? Don't get me wrong, it's not a "great" thing, but the code you supply here is provided without license, free for all, that's all were saying.  You could have pointed the OP back to the original answer with the single line of correction ;)

Comment: @KickButtowski why? you don't have to

Comment: @danbst what do you mean?

Comment: @KickButtowski "this is the rule. if I use others code, I always put source" -> this is wrong rule. You don't have to put link to original if you use other's code

Answer (score 1):

You can try in this way

Eg:

```
int[] input = new int[]{1, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 1, 7, 3, 7, 7, 7};
int temp =input[0];
boolean isFirst=true;
for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if(isFirst){
       System.out.print(temp);
       isFirst=false;
    }
    if (temp != input[i]) {
       System.out.print(input[i]);
    }
     temp = input[i];
}
```

Out put:

```
 1251737
```

Logic: I am taking only first occurrence of continuous numbers.

Comment: Ok, Now change the line to `int[] input = new int[]{0, 1, 1, 2};`

Comment: @Krumia out put :`012`

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify code a lot, if you don't want to remove all duplicates, only closest one.

```
public class Q3 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int [] input=new int[]{1 ,2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 1, 7, 3, 7, 7, 7};
        int base = input[0];
        System.out.print(base);
        for (int current : input) {
            if (current != base) {
                base = current;
                System.out.print(" " + base);
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 5 1 7 3 7
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int [] input = new int[]{1 ,2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 1, 7, 3, 7, 7, 7};
int previous = 0;
boolean started = false; // loop is not started yet

for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
{
    // if the loop is not started, or the number is not equal to previously printed number...
    if (!started || input[i] != previous) {
        System.out.print(input[i] + " ");
        previous = input[i];
    }
    started = true;
}
```