# Pulling distinct values from a array in java

Tags: java, arrays, unique

Have a program where the user inputs 10 int values into the array. Lastly I need to pull out the distinct values and display them. Added my second for loop which would determine if the the value is distinct (i.e. meaning if the number appears multiple times it is only displayed once).

For instance, let say I pass in the numbers: 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 6, 3, 4, 5, 2 the distinct array should only contain numbers {1, 2, 3, 6, 4, 5}

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class ArrayDistinct {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

 // Create arrays & variables  
 int arrayLength = 10;
 int[] numbers = new int[arrayLength];
 int[] distinctArray = new int[arrayLength];
 int count = 0;

 System.out.println("Program starting...");
 System.out.print("Please enter in " + numbers.length + " numbers: ");

 for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  numbers[i] = input.nextInt();
 }

 for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  int temp = numbers[i];
  int tempTwo = numbers[i + 1];

  if (tempTwo == temp) {
   count++;
   distinctArray[i] = temp;
  }
 } 

 // Print out results

} // end main
} // end class
```

Comment: What are "the distinct" values?  I think you are presuming some prior knowledge on our part.  Please explain your question better.

Comment: Consider using a set only allows unique values...

Comment: @brso05 I'm guessing it's homework; he hasn't got to Sets yet.

Answer (score 5):

In `Java 8`

**Stream< T > distinct()**

> Returns a stream consisting of the distinct elements (according to
>   Object.equals(Object)) of this stream. For ordered streams, the
>   selection of distinct elements is stable (for duplicated elements, the
>   element appearing first in the encounter order is preserved.) For
>   unordered streams, no stability guarantees are made.

Code:

```
   Integer[] array = new Integer[]{5, 10, 20, 58, 10};
   Stream.of(array)
         .distinct()
         .forEach(i -> System.out.print(" " + i));
```

Output:

```
5,10,20,58
```

[Read More About distinct function](http://blog.jooq.org/2014/06/13/java-8-friday-10-subtle-mistakes-when-using-the-streams-api/)

Comment: @Chewy take a look at this link for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17967114/how-to-remove-duplicates-from-an-array-in-java

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

```
Set<Integer> uniqueNumbers = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(numbers));
```

`uniqueNumbers` will contain only unique values

Comment: What if i don't want to sort data?

Answer (score 2):

Try this code.. it will work

```
package Exercises;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class E5Second
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner In = new Scanner(System.in);
        int [] number = new int [10];
        fillArr(number);

        boolean [] distinct = new boolean [10];

        int count = 0; 
        for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i++) 
        {
            if (isThere(number,i) == false)
            {
                distinct[i] = true;
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\nThe number of distinct numbers is  " + count);
        System.out.print("The distinct numbers are: ");
        displayDistinct(number, distinct);
    }
    public static void fillArr(int [] number)
    {
        Scanner In = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter ten integers ");
        for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i++)
            number[i] = In.nextInt();
    }
    public static boolean isThere(int [] number, int i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            if(number[i] == number[j])
                return true;
        return false;
    }
    public static void  displayDistinct(int [] number, boolean [] distinct)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < distinct.length; i++)
            if (distinct[i]) 
                System.out.print(number[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible logic: If you're supposed to only sort out  "unique" numbers, then you'll want to test each number as it's entered and added to the first array, and loop through the array and see if it's equal to any of the numbers already there; if not, add it to the "unique" array.

Comment: Edited my original post with the logic that you stated .. if this is not correct, could explain how I could rewrite, without giving me the answer

Comment: @Chewy I put comment on my answer go there it helps u

Answer (score 0):

Sets in java doesn't allow duplicates:

```
    Integer[] array = new Integer[]{5, 10, 20, 58, 10};
    HashSet<Integer> uniques = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(array));
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you:

```
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

     // Create arrays & variables  
     int arrayLength = 10;
     int[] numbers = new int[arrayLength];
     int[] distinctArray = new int[arrayLength];
     int count = 0;
     Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();

     System.out.println("Program starting...");
     System.out.print("Please enter in " + numbers.length + " numbers: ");

     for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
         set.add(input.nextInt());
     }

     for(Integer i : set)
     {
         System.out.println("" + i);
     }
```

This will only add unique values to the set.

Answer (score 0):

```
int a[] = { 2, 4, 5, 3, 3, 3, 4, 6 };
int flag = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
{  
    flag = 0;
    for (int j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++)
    {
        if (a[i] == a[j])
        {
            flag = 1;
        }
    }

    if (flag == 0)
    {
        System.out.println(a[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you expand your answer to include an explanation of why this is helpful to the OP's requirements?

Answer (score 0):

You can use stream() and then use distinct() which will remove all the duplicates value from the passed int array.

Code:

```
    int numbers [] = {1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 6, 3, 4, 5, 2};
    List<Integer> distinctNumbers = Arrays.stream(numbers).boxed().distinct().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
    distinctNumbers.stream().forEach(s-> System.out.println(s));
```