# Java - count duplicates in array without using outside classes or methods?

Tags: java, arrays, duplicates

I need to count the number of dupes in an array, but I'm constrained to only using arrays, no HashSets or ArrayLists.

Here are example inputs with their expected outputs:

```
numDuplicates(new double[] { }) --> 0
numDuplicates(new double[] { 11.0 }) --> 0
numDuplicates(new double[] { 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0 }) --> 3
numDuplicates(new double[] { 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 22.0, 33.0, 44.0, 44.0, 44.0, 44.0, 44.0, 55.0, 55.0, 66.0, 77.0, 88.0, 88.0 }) --> 9
numDuplicates(new double[] { 11.0, 22.0, 33.0, 44.0, 44.0, 44.0, 44.0, 44.0, 55.0, 55.0, 66.0, 77.0, 88.0 }) --> 5
```

This is the code I have, but it counts duplicates after each number, returning an inflated count, i.e. {11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0} returns 6 instead of 3:

```
public static int numDuplicates (double[] list) {

    int dupCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < list.length; j++) {
            if (list[i] == list[j]) {
                dupCount++;
            }
        }
    }

    return dupCount; //TODO1: fix this
}
```

Note: I'm new on Stack, I tried searching thoroughly but couldn't find an array duplicate question that had similar input/output to mine, but I'm sorry if someone has already asked this.

Comment: Based on the example you gave, it looks like you are supposed to find the longest duplicate not just count all the duplicates

Comment: Perhaps this may answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31738825/9488265

Comment: No actually it looks like you're right ignore previous comment

Comment: All you need to do to fix your code is insert a `break;` after you increment `dupCount`. That way you only count each duplicate once.

Comment: @4castle, that worked, thank you so much!

Comment: Are the duplicates always consecutive? Should `new double[] { 1, 2, 1 }` return 0 or 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple fix:

```
public static int numDuplicates (double[] list) {

    int dupCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < list.length; j++, i++) { // HERE it is
            if (list[i] == list[j]) {
                dupCount++;
            }
        }
    }

    return dupCount;
}
```

What I did was to increment `i` in addition to `j`. What this did was to start `i` at the place where `j` stopped. The reason I thought to do that was because you said it was returning an inflated count, so I figured it must be because you are doing too many counts and that was exactly what was happening.

`i` was always following in increments of `1` rather than increments of the `size of the last duplicate counts` found, so it was always repeating counts.

As to how the `j++, i++` works - it is just a series of expressions. Java allows you to separate expressions that evaluate to the same type, using a comma.

---

As per the comments, you can remove the outer loop:

```
public static int numDuplicates (double[] list) {

    int dupCount = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (list[i] == list[i - 1]) {
            dupCount++;
        }
    }
    return dupCount;
}
```

Comment: Wow, I never knew you could do this! But how does j++, i++ work?

Comment: That worked! I'm new to Java, would you mind explaining what that changed functionally?

Comment: Explanation coming guys, hang tight

Comment: If you increment `i` and `j` at the same time, they will always be adjacent indexes. You might as well remove the outer loop and calculate `i` as `j - 1`.

Comment: @4castle, noted

Answer (score 0):

You could use another array like so:

```
public static int numDuplicates(double[] list) {

    double[] duparray = new double[list.length];
    int dupCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < list.length; j++) {
            if (list[i] == list[j] && !(list[i] == duparray[i])) {
                duparray[i] = list[i];
                dupCount++;
            }
        }
    }

    return dupCount;
}
```

Comment: This won't work if the input array contains any zeros. A better solution would be to use a `boolean[]` array instead that indicates if the value at that index has already been counted as a duplicate.

Comment: If the input array was `new double[]{ 0, 0 }` for example, it would already count the values as equal to the default values in `dupArray`, so it would return `0` duplicates instead of `1`.