# How to prevent duplicate items from being added to the matrix

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a matrix that has a set of elements and duplicates
I want to add items to ArrayList with no duplicate elements

```
 package window1;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
  public class Mine {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     ArrayList<String> listName = new ArrayList<>();

       String sal[]={"val","sa","de","dal","val","sa","de"};

       for(int i =0;i<sal.length;i++){

          listName.add(sal[i]);
                    }

      for(int j=0;j<listName.size();j++){
         System.out.println(listName.get(j));

                    }

            }

      }
```

Comment: You can use `HashSet` instead which avoids duplicates

Comment: This questions has been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17967114/how-to-efficiently-remove-duplicates-from-an-array-without-using-set

Comment: Thank you all of the solutions that were developed were good but using HashSet was more accurate and more effective for me
Especially when you use it to filter it on BaseAdapter in Android Studio

Answer (score 1):

You can simply verify if the item exists in your list before adding it, using the `contains()` method.

The [java.util.ArrayList.contains(Object)](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arraylist_contains.htm)  method returns true if this list contains the specified element.

```
package window1;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Mine {
private ArrayList<String> listName = new ArrayList<>();
private String sal[]={"val","sa","de","dal","val","sa","de"};

     public static void main(String[] args) {

        for(int i =0;i<sal.length;i++)
        {

             if(!listname.contains(sal[i])) // If the element does not exist...
                 listName.add(sal[i]); // Add him
        }

       for(int j=0;j<listName.size();j++) System.out.println(listName.get(j));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use contains method :

```
if(!listName.contains(sal[i]))
                listName.add(sal[i]);
```

OUTPUT

```
val
sa
de
dal
```

**(!listName.contains(sal[i]))**

contains will return if item already in list and using `!` negating the condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(listName);

System.out.println("Set values .....");
for (String temp : set) System.out.println(temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Hashset to remove duplicates

```
Set<String> noDupSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(new String[] {"val1","val2","val1"}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use **HashSet** instead of **ArrayList**. Example:

```
HashSet<String> set=new HashSet<String>();  
  set.add("Ravi");  
  set.add("Vijay");  
  set.add("Ravi");  
  set.add("Ajay");  
  //Traversing elements  
  Iterator<String> itr=set.iterator();  
  while(itr.hasNext()){  
   System.out.println(itr.next());  
  }
```

It will display Ravi, Vijay and Ajay as output. Note Ravi added twice but it adds only once because **HashSet contains unique elements only.**

**Or**

If you want to add unique elements in **ArrayList** then you will need to add items in HashSet first then you can add its item in **ArrayList** as shown below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayList<String> listName = new ArrayList<String>();
        HashSet<String> newListName = new HashSet<String>();

        String sal[]={"val","sa","de","dal","val","sa","de"};

        // add unique items in HashSet(newListName)
        for(int i=0; i<sal.length; i++){
            newListName.add(sal[i]);
        }

        // add items of HashSet into ArrayList(listName)
        for(String s: newListName) {
            listName.add(s);
        }

        // display ArrayList(listName)
        for(String s: listName) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First convert your array to hashSet.Which will remove the duplicates.

Next convert the HashSet to ArrayList.(Your desired Data Structure collection)

Check The Code bellow.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
        String sal[]={"val","sa","de","dal","val","sa","de"};
        HashSet<String> ss = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(sal));
        System.out.println("HashSet-");
        System.out.println(ss);
        ArrayList<String> asl= new ArrayList<String>(ss);
        System.out.println("ArrayList-");
        System.out.println(asl);
}
```

O/P:

```
HashSet-
[de, val, sa, dal]
ArrayList-
[de, val, sa, dal]
```