# Removing duplicates from array without using any collection api of java

Tags: java

Can you please advise I have the below array for which I want to remove duplicates but without using any collection api  , please advise how to achieve this...

```
  int[][] test = new int[][]{
            {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5},
            {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
            {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7},
            {1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},};
```

Comment: Do you want to remove duplicates in the same row or in the whole matrix?

Comment: @Dinosaur in the whole matrix.

Comment: http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.il/2014/01/how-to-remove-duplicates-from-array-java-without-collection-API.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10056729/java-remove-duplicates-from-an-array?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Since you are dealing with int array and values are relatively small I'd suggest you to create temporary `boolean` array where the numbers from the source array are used as indexes. Then you just have to iterate over the source array, put `true` to appropriate cell of your temporary array. At the next iteration go over the temporary array and indexes of elements that are `true`.

Comment: Thanks a lot can you please post the code also that will help me to grasp more , request you to take input array as I have mentioned above while explaning

Comment: @user3270422 This absolutely sounds like you are asking us to do your homework. The guiding principle for this is: "Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first. If we can't see enough work on your part your question will likely be booed off the stage; it will be voted down and closed." See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions