# Remove duplicate elements from array along with element in Java 1.7

Tags: java, arrays, collections

I need to write a method where a `int[]` will be supplied as an input and it should return an array, but with all of the numbers that occur more than n times removed entirely.

```
Inputs:
    (int list) data = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5]

Output:
    (int list) [1, 4]
```

These are the steps i have tried.

1. Copy the int array to ArrayList (inputList).
2. Create a LinkedHashset to find unique values
3. Iterate LH and find the collection frequency of ArrayList with iterator.

   ```
   int[] intArray = new int[0];

   if(n!=0){
       if(data.length<100){

           ArrayList<Integer> inputList = new ArrayList<Integer>(data.length);
           //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
           for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
               inputList.add(Integer.valueOf(data[i]));
           }

           LinkedHashSet<Integer> lhs = new LinkedHashSet<>(inputList);

           intArray = new int[lhs.size()];
           int i=0;
           int j=0;
           Iterator<Integer> itr = lhs.iterator();
           while(itr.hasNext()){
               Integer shiftNumber = itr.next();

               if(Collections.frequency(inputList, shiftNumber)==1) {
                   intArray[i++] = shiftNumber.intValue();
                   j++;
               }


           }
           intArray = Arrays.copyOf(intArray, j);
           return intArray;
       }
   }

   return intArray;
   ```

I am able to achieve the results with the above snippet.However, I need suggestions in reducing the piece of code and improving performance by using any algorithms or other collection objects.

Comment: Looks like you want to post to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), SO isn't for improving upon working code and rather fixing broken code.

Comment: Or you can look for answers to compare and see other solutions to test. [Removing Duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10056729/java-remove-duplicates-from-an-array)

Comment: @Underbalanced Please re-read the statement. The ask is to remove the item which has the duplicates.

Inputs:
    (int list) data = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5]
Output:
    (int list) [1, 4]

Comment: Why -1 for the question? I hope it's not a duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are likely overcomplicating the algorithm. It might be simpler to just map each value to its frequency and then copy those values with frequency less than `n`. Also note that you don't need to explicitly covert between `int` and `Integer`: Java does it for you automatically.

```
int[] output = new int[input.length];
Map<Integer,Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();
int size = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    counts.put(input[i], counts.getOrDefault(input[i], 0) + 1);
}
for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (counts.get(input[i]) < n)
        output[size++] = input[i];
}
return Arrays.copyOf(output, size);
```

If you are familiar with Java 8 streams then the code can be substantially reduced:

```
Map<Integer,Integer> count = Arrays.stream(input).boxed()
    .collect(groupingBy(identity(), counting()));
return Arrays.stream(input).filter(i -> count.get(i) < n).toArray();
```

Comment: for java 8 you could use the more consise method for computing map values.  for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    counts.compute(input[i], (k, v) -> v == null ? 1 : v++);
}

Answer (score 3):

You could use a map instead.

The map key would represent the values found in the array; the map value would be a counter.

You iterate your array, and for each element you either put a counter=1 (when finding that value the first time); or you simply increase that counter.

Finally, you collect only those map keys that show a counter value of 1.