# How to remove duplicates from a list based on a custom java object not a primitive type?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, set

Before I post this question, I found somehow similar question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203984/how-do-i-remove-repeated-elements-from-arraylist). But the answer was based on a String. However, I have a different situation here. I am not trying to remove String but another object called AwardYearSource. This class has an int attribute called year. So I want to remove duplicates based on the year. i.e if there is year 2010 mentioned more than once, I want to remove that AwardYearSource object. How can I do that?

Comment: Java 8 way is also quite nice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699371/java-8-distinct-by-property

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The simplest way to remove elements based on a field is as follows (preserving order):

```
Map<Integer, AwardYearSource> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for (AwardYearSource ays : list) {
  map.put(ays.getYear(), ays);
}
list.clear();
list.addAll(map.values());
```

Comment: Thank you. It solved my problem. However I changed the first line of your code  to  Map<Integer, AwardSource> map = new LinkedHashMap<Integer,AwardSource>(); .... otherwise it won't compile.

Comment: Excellent dude...,

Comment: Nice and Easy way... Super

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to override `hashCode()` and `equals(Object obj)` for your object. Since it just has one field you want to use to determine equality, this is pretty straightforward. Something like:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
  if (obj == null || !(obj instanceof AwardYearSource)) {
    return false;
  }
  return (this.year == ((AwardYearSource)obj).year);
}
public int hashCode() {
  return this.year;
}
```

Then you can just stick all of the objects into a `Set` to remove duplicates:

```
Set<AwardYearSource> set = new Set<AwardYearSource>();

set.add(new AwardYearSource(2011));
set.add(new AwardYearSource(2012));
set.add(new AwardYearSource(2011));

for (AwardYearSource aws : set) {
  System.out.println(aws.year);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fairly simply.  Although something bugs me about the map versions (not that I doubt they'd work, it just seems like overkill, somehow - although this version isn't necessarily any better in that regard).
Answer is functional, and threadsafe (assuming `AwardYearSource` is immutable).

```
public static List<AwardYearSource> removeDuplicateYears(
                                          final Collection<AwardYearSource> awards) {
    final ArrayList<AwardYearSource> input = new ArrayList<AwardYearSource>(awards);
    // If there's only one element (or none), guaranteed unique.
    if (input.size() <= 1) {
        return input;
    }
    final HashSet<Integer> years = new HashSet<Integer>(input.size(), 1);
    final Iterator<AwardYearSource> iter = input.iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()) {
        final AwardYearSource award = iter.next();
        final Integer year = award.getYear();
        if (years.contains(year)) {
            iter.remove();
        } else {
            years.add(year);
        }
    }
    return input;       

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a map and store your objects with the year as a key:

```
Map<Integer, AwardYearSource> map = new HashMap<Integer, AwardYearSource>();
map.put(someAwardYearSource1.getYear(), someAwardYearSource1);
map.put(someAwardYearSource2.getYear(), someAwardYearSource2);

etc.
```

At the end the map will contain unique values by year, which you can call with the values method:

```
Collection<AwardYearSource> noDups = map.values();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a HashMap object with int as the key type and your class as the value type. Then iterate over the list and insert each element to the map using:

```
mymap.put(source.year, source);
```

Then remove all elements from the origianl list and iterate over the map and insert each element to the list.

Comment: Really?  Could you maybe provide more details?  Although at least one of the iterators is unnecessary - see some of the other answers.  And this would have some nasty side-effects, if used in a threaded context.

Comment: Maybe you have posted this comment on the wrong answer? I don't see any iterators in my solutions and it's quite thread safe.

Comment: You explicitly mention iterate, and you're going to be using at least one _implicit_ (compiler generated, in the case of the for-each construct) iterator.  If this is being packaged up in it's own method (which it should be), then removing items from the original list is **absolutely NOT** threadsafe.

Comment: I don't think thread safety is quite an issue here at least according to the question that was asked. I think the map-based solutions offered by me and others are the most simple ones.

Answer (score 0):

If your AwardYearSource class overrides equals and hashcode methods (Eclipse can generate both), then you can add them to a Set. The Set will not contain any duplicates.

```
public class AwardYearSource
{
    private final int year;

    public AwardYearSource(int year)
    {
        this.year = year;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + year;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        AwardYearSource other = (AwardYearSource) obj;
        if (year != other.year)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return String.valueOf(year);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Set<AwardYearSource> set = new HashSet<AwardYearSource>();
        set.add(new AwardYearSource(2000));
        set.add(new AwardYearSource(2000));
        set.add(new AwardYearSource(2000));
        set.add(new AwardYearSource(2000));

        System.out.println(set);
    }
}
```

The output is [2000]. Only one item in the set.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
list.removeIf(i -> set.contains(i.getYear()) ? true : !set.add(i.getYear()));
```

This should help wherein, duplication is decided based on certain property (or combination of properties), year in this case. Hope this helps.