# Removing duplicate elements from a List

Tags: java, list, duplicates

I have developed an array list.

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

list.add("1");
list.add("2");
list.add("3");
list.add("3");
list.add("5");
list.add("6");
list.add("7");
list.add("7");
list.add("1");
list.add("10");
list.add("2");
list.add("12");
```

But as seen above it contains many duplicate elements. I want to remove all duplicates from that list. For this I think first I need to convert the list into a set.

Does Java provide the functionality of converting a list into a set? Are there other facilities to remove duplicates from a list?

Comment: Why didn't you create a Set to begin with?

Comment: Set<String> Set = new HashSet<String>(list);

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remove repeated elements from ArrayList?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203984/how-do-i-remove-repeated-elements-from-arraylist)

Comment: You should accept an answer

Answer (score 25):

You can convert to a Set with:

```
Set<String> aSet = new HashSet<String>(list);
```

Or you can convert to a set and back to a list with:

```
list = new ArrayList<String>(new HashSet<String>(list));
```

Both of these, however, are not likely to preserve the order of the elements. To preserve order, you can use a `HashSet` as an auxiliary structure while iterating:

```
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
HashSet<String> lookup = new HashSet<String>();
for (String item : list) {
    if (lookup.add(item)) {
        // Set.add returns false if item is already in the set
        list2.add(item);
    }
}
list = list2;
```

In the case of duplicates, only the first occurrence will appear in the result. If you want only the last occurrence to appear, that's a tougher problem. I'd tackle it by reversing the input list, applying the above, and then reversing the result.

Comment: Hi Ted , thanks a lot could you please explain list = new ArrayList<String>(new HashSet<String>(list)); alittle bit in first we are converting list to a set and in second trying to convert set back to list.

Comment: @user1351820 - Converting to a `Set` eliminates duplicates. Converting back to a `List` gives you a collection with a fixed (but undetermined) order, where you can access elements by index. If all you need is a collection (without any specific order -- including possibly different order on different iterations of the unchanged collection), just go with the first option. If you need to preserve the original order, go with the third.

Answer (score 10):

This:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
set.addAll(list);
list.clear();
list.addAll(set);
```

Comment: @Abshiek, Thanks, so ultimately java provides us the functionality of converting list into set.

Comment: @user1351820 Actually Java provides a constructor to initialize a `Collection` with any other `Collection` so it's even wider :)

Answer (score 7):

**Java 8** way:
`list.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());`

done :)

Comment: You still return a `List` although you have removed the duplicates. This answers the base question, but the original poster comments that he expects an answer about 'converting a list into a set'.

Comment: You could just do `Collectors.toSet()` at the end instead of `.toList()` if Set is desired.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to preserve elements order then use LinkedHashSet instead of HashSet

```
Set<String> mySet = new LinkedHashSet<String>(list);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the normal constructor:

```
ArrayList<T> yourList;
HashSet<T> set = new HashSet<T>(yourList);
```

And you'll have a new view of the items, with duplicates removed, but you will lose ordering. This is true in every answer posted so far. To keep ordering you should iterate on the existing list and remove an element only if it's a duplicate (which can be done using a set to check if an element was already found).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a set in the first place or convert into it:

```
 Set<String> set = new TreeSet<String>(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.scjp.dump.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.Iterator;

import java.util.List;

public class ArrayListTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Integer> mylist2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        List<Integer> mylist1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        mylist1.add(3);
        mylist1.add(3);
        mylist1.add(5);
        mylist1.add(9);
        mylist1.add(2);
        mylist1.add(5);
        mylist1.add(5);
        mylist1.add(3);
        mylist1.add(3);
        mylist1.add(3);
        mylist1.add(9);
        mylist1.add(56);
        System.out.println(mylist1);
        Iterator<Integer> itr1 = mylist1.listIterator();
        while (itr1.hasNext()) {
            Integer itn1 = (Integer) itr1.next();
            if (mylist2.contains(itn1) == false)
                mylist2.add(itn1);
        }

        System.out.println(mylist2);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some way you can achieve this.

**Using Java 8**:

```
List<String> distinctLambda=originalList.stream()
           .distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
 System.out.println(distinctLambda);
```

**Using Set**:

```
Set<String> distinctSet=new HashSet<>(originalList);
        System.out.println(distinctSet);
```

**Normal for loop**:

```
List<String> distinctNewList=new ArrayList<>();
        for (String temp:originalList) {
            if(distinctNewList.size()==0){
                distinctNewList.add(temp);
                continue;
            }

            if(!distinctNewList.contains(temp)){
                distinctNewList.add(temp);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(distinctNewList);
```

Here is your data set:

```
ArrayList<String> originalList = new ArrayList<>();
        originalList.add("1");
        originalList.add("2");
        originalList.add("3");
        originalList.add("3");
        originalList.add("5");
        originalList.add("6");
        originalList.add("7");
        originalList.add("7");
        originalList.add("1");
        originalList.add("10");
        originalList.add("2");
        originalList.add("12");
```