# remove duplicates from List<String[]>

Tags: java, list, duplicate-data, duplicates

I'm looking for a nice way to remove duplicates from a list.

```
List<String[]> rowList = new ArrayList();
    rowList.add(new String[]{"1","a", "abc"});
    rowList.add(new String[]{"2","b", "def"});
    rowList.add(new String[]{"3","c", "ghi"});
    rowList.add(new String[]{"4","a", "jkl"});
    rowList.add(new String[]{"5","d", "mno"});
    rowList.add(new String[]{"6","e", "pqr"});
    rowList.add(new String[]{"7","b", "stu"});
```

From this rwoList, i only want entries: 1,2,3,5 and 6. This means i have only one column of intrest, in this case column 2 (a, b, c,..)
This is only an easy example i have to handle hugh amount of tables which have 300 columns and min 300000 rows. Another important point is, that i don't won't loose the orientation within the list.

Note: I receive the data from a csv file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10370750/removing-duplicate-elements-from-a-list

Comment: Every common problem. Seems like no efforts were made to google it. So down voting.

Comment: Do you retrieve these data from a DB? Is it legal to have duplicates or does it indicate inconsistency?

Comment: Not directly, I read the data from a csv file into my application.

Comment: @HaveANiceDay You too :)

Comment: Why don't you use a specific class to store the data rather than an array of strings?

Comment: @Andy897: I searched a lot, I your link doesn't work for me!

Comment: The direction in which Heuster is pointing is: Make a "Data-Class" that implements `equals` in a way, so that it returns true if your critical column (or columns) is the same. Then use a [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  List<String[]> rowList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
  rowList.add(new String[]{"1","a", "abc"});
  rowList.add(new String[]{"2","b", "def"});
  rowList.add(new String[]{"3","c", "ghi"});
  rowList.add(new String[]{"4","a", "jkl"});
  rowList.add(new String[]{"5","d", "mno"});
  rowList.add(new String[]{"6","e", "pqr"});
  rowList.add(new String[]{"7","b", "stu"});

  Set<String[]> s = new TreeSet<String[]>(new Comparator<String[]>() {
         @Override
         public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2) {
                return o1[1].compareTo(o2[1]);
        }
   });
```

Removing the duplicates by adding to set `"s"`

```
   s.addAll(rowList);
   List<Object> res = Arrays.asList(s.toArray());
```

Printing your result

```
   for (Object object : res) {
         String[] array = (String[])object;
         System.out.println(array[0]+" "+ array[1] +", "+array[2]);
    }
```

**Output**

```
1 a, abc
2 b, def
3 c, ghi
5 d, mno
6 e, pqr
```

Comment: As I understood the OP, the order shall not be changed. This would sort by critical column, wouldn't it?

Comment: I'd suggest using [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html), because: "Hash table and linked list implementation of the Set interface, with predictable iteration order."

Comment: @Fildor  Yes you are correct. In order to use LinkedHashSet we need to have pojo with implementation of Comparator or Comparable. I think with String[] it will be little complicated.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your solution is exactly what i'm looking for ;) simple and fast enougth.

Answer (score 1):

Make a custom method `isContain(List<String[]> rowList, String string)`

```
private static boolean isContain(List<String[]> rowList, String secStr) {
    for (String[] strings : rowList) {
       if(strings[1].equals(secStr)){
           return true;
       }   
    }
    return false;
}
```

Check this method before add item to `List` to remove duplicate item, like:

```
 List<String[]> rowList = new ArrayList();
    String[] sts= new String[]{"1", "a", "abc"};
    boolean contain= isContain(rowList,sts[1]);
    if(!contain){
        rowList.add(sts);
    }
```