# How to use equals() to create ArrayList of unique elements

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have to add only unique elements to an `ArrayList`. How can I override the `equals` method for that purpose? I want something like:

```
public boolean equals (Object in) {
    if(in == null) {
        return false;
    }
    else if(in instanceof UniqueFruits) {
        // ?? check whether the newly added element exists or not           
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }       
}
```

How to check whether the newly added element exists or not? I have to check on the Fruit Names.

Comment: You must override `equals` and `hashCode` methods in order to do this.

Comment: But how? I need the code for the check part.

Comment: You must compare the attribute values inside your `if( in instanceof UniqueFruits) { ... }` code to return true or false, depending on your rules, like fruit name or whatever you want/need

Comment: Even once you get equals() working for your custom object, you'll still need extra logic to decide whether or not to add it to your ArrayList.  If you need a unique collection, you can use one of the [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) implementations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use a [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) implementation. If order doesn't matter, just use [`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html). If you want to keep insertion-order, use [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html). Or, to maintain natural ordering, use [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html).

In any case, make sure to override your element object's `equals` method. What you have is a good start. After checking `in instanceof UniqueFruits`, cast `in` to `UniqueFruits`:

```
UniqueFruits uf = (UniqueFruits)in;
```

You can then check each relevant field using `equals` in turn (make sure to check for `null` first if a field is nullable). Any modern IDE will help you generate `equals` automatically. It may be educational to try it yourself first, then compare with the generated version.

Make sure to override `hashCode` also (IDEs will similarly help you with this, and there is plenty of reading online about the matter - just search).

If you use `TreeSet` (or some other `SortedSet` implementation), your element object should either implement [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) or else you should provide the `SortedSet` with a [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `Set` instead of `ArrayList` for storing unique elements. It is easier and cleaner.

As per the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) for `Set`, here's what it says:

> A collection that contains no duplicate elements. More formally, sets
>   contain no pair of elements e1 and e2 such that e1.equals(e2), and at
>   most one null element. As implied by its name, this interface models
>   the mathematical set abstraction

Here's an [SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203984/how-do-i-remove-repeated-elements-from-arraylist) that talks about how to remove repeated elements from `ArrayList`. However, you would notice that most of the solutions provided uses an implementation of `Set` to achieve what you want to do. In any case, over-riding `equals()` as you've done will not help achieve your objective. *If it's not too much of a trouble (I don't understand why you need to stick with an `ArrayList` given your actual requirement, I would **strongly** suggest moving to a `Set` implementation.*

Comment: I know set can help better but I require this with an ArrayList only.

Answer (score 0):

If your fruitname class has 2 attributes, like `fruitname` and `fruitclass` then

your check code should be

```
UniqueFruits current = (UniqueFruits) in;
if(this.fruitname.equals(current.fruitname) && this.fruitclass.equals(current.fruitclass)) {
  return true;
}else{
   return false;
}
```

And coming to hashcode ask your IDE to generate the hasdcode for `UniqueFruits` Class.
And use `Set` instead of `ArrayList`

On a lighter note Your IDE can even generate equals() for you.