# In java, how to replace a duplicate number in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I remove repeated elements from ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203984/how-do-i-remove-repeated-elements-from-arraylist)

I want to replace a duplicate number (if any) that i store in an ArrayList. I obtianed the numbers for a Random variable. Here is the class.

```
import java.util.*;

public class RandomNumbers {
// instance variables
private ArrayList<Integer> randomNumberList = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
private Random randomNums = new Random();

public RandomNumbers(){
    // generating and adding random numbers to the list
    for (int i=0; i<MemoryGame.totalAnswers; i++)
        randomNumberList.add(randomNums.nextInt(32));

    System.out.println("Numbers in the list: " + randomNumberList);
    System.out.println("");
}

public ArrayList<Integer> getRandomNumbers(){
    return randomNumberList;
}
}
```

My school book tells me how to add,remove and retrieve a number, but not how to replace one that is duplicated.

thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "replace"? Is it that you want to keep generating random numbers until you get one you haven't already got?

Comment: duplication in duplication question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203984/how-do-i-remove-repeated-elements-from-arraylist

Comment: Just a comment, BTW, is `MemoryGame.totalAnswers` always smaller than 32? If not, you may run into problems....

Comment: I need 8 random numbers fro

Comment: For a reasonably sized set of distinct numbers to randomize, I would ***use a [Fisher-Yates] shuffle*** and then pick the first N (could be up to the entire input size) results. I find this approach cleaner in general. (The Fisher-Yates shuffle can also be implemented in such a way that numbers are generated as a stream without requiring full computation.)

Comment: I need 8 random numbers from 0-31 that are not duplicated. The Value in MemoryGame.totalAnswers is 8. I'm going to resource HashSet tonight. I didn't know about it since I'm still I'm my first semester at school.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not limited to `ArrayList`, use a `HashSet<Integer>` instead (or better yet, a [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html)). `HashSet<Integer>` will garantee you not to have duplicated values in the collection, `LinkedHashSet<Integer>` will do the same and also preserve the ordering the the items.

If you insist on having an `ArrayList`, then do this :

```
public RandomNumbers(){
    HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();

    // generating and adding random numbers to the list
    //for (int i=0; i<MemoryGame.totalAnswers; i++)
    while (set.size()<MemoryGame.totalAnswers)
        set.add(randomNums.nextInt(32));

    randomNumberList.addAll(set);  // dump the set in your ArrayList

    System.out.println("Numbers in the list: " + randomNumberList);
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Also, if `MemoryGame.totalAnswers == 32`, then you can speed up this process with a [random list](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)) instead :

```
public RandomNumbers(){
    // generating and adding random numbers to the list
    for (int i=0; i<MemoryGame.totalAnswers; i++)
        randomNumberList.add(i);

    Collections.shuffle(randomNumberList);

    System.out.println("Numbers in the list: " + randomNumberList);
    System.out.println("");
}
```

** **Update** **

Since `MemoryGame.totalAnswers == 8`, forget the last snippet. I'm leaving it there if anyone would happend to need it. You can skip the use of a `Set` entirely by folllowing [pst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14078292/in-java-how-to-replace-a-duplicate-number-in-an-arraylist/14078312#comment19465721_14078292)'s suggestion :

```
public RandomNumbers(){
    // generating and adding random numbers to the list
    for (int i=0; i<32; i++)
        randomNumberList.add(i);

    Collections.shuffle(randomNumberList);

    // keep only the first ones we need
    randomNumberList.removeRange(MemoryGame.totalAnswers + 1, 32);

    System.out.println("Numbers in the list: " + randomNumberList);
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: With the updated comments, I added yet another workable solution, without using a `Set`. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

For replacing an element in a position use the [`set()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set%28int,%20E%29) method:

```
randomNumberList.set(index, element);
```

Of course, the logic to find out *which* elements are duplicated in the first place is up to you; if it doesn't make sense to have duplicate numbers for your problem, better use a [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) data structure (for instance: [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html), or [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) if preserving insertion order when iterating is important for you) and keep adding random elements to the set until it has the desired size.

Answer (score 1):

If the ultimate objective is a random list of distinct numbers, and the range of possible numbers is not much larger than the number of results required, consider a [shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) rather than replacing duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is as per your last comment

> 8 random, non-repeated numbers from 0-31

You don't need any instance variables, random number generating code, or instance methods.
All you need is just this:

```
public static List<Integer> getRandomNumbers() {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        list.add(i);
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    return list.subList(0, 8);
}
```

Comment: I tried this method, but somehow i get duplicate number with this method.

Comment: It is totally impossible to get duplicate numbers with this code, because each number 0-31 is added only once. What did you do to "try" it, exactly?

Comment: I replace my getRandomNumbers method with yours and delete what i had in the constructor method. But if I use it in the constructor and return the value through getRandomNumbers method it works just fine. is there any way to remove the non-use elements after shuffling. ei delete index from 9-31 after shuffling. I dont if it make since to delete them but i would think so, because efficiency. Thanks for the help.

Comment: to "delete" the used ones, do this: `myList = list.subList(8, list.size())`