# Extract only repeated elements in a list in Java

Tags: java, list

A Java list has repeated elements like

```
[cat, apple, iphone, football, apple, adam, apple, football, cat, people, cat]
```

- `cat` repeated 3 times
- `football` repeated 2 times
- `apple` repeated 3 times

How to extract only the repeated elements from the list such that the final list has
`[cat, apple, football]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Set`:

```
List<String> findDuplicates(List<String> original) {
    Set<String> seen = new HashSet<String>();
    Set<String> seenTwice = new HashSet<String>();

    for (String s: original) {
        if (!seen.add(s)) {
            seenTwice.add(s);
        }
    }
    return new ArrayList<String>(seenTwice);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

something like:

```
String temp;
ArrayList<String> newStrings= new ArrayList<String>();
int x =0;
while(x < list.length){
 list.temp = get(x);
 for(int i =0; i < list.length; i++){
  if(temp.equals(list.get(i)) && i != x)
   newStrings.add(temp);



 }
x++
}
```

think that will add them to a new arraylist for you from the old one

Comment: The while loop is infinite. Also, this code never checks `i != x`, so once you fix the infinite loop, it will end up adding every element to the `ArrayList`, whether or not it's a duplicate.

Comment: @Brigham Fixed it up, just tried to write it up real quick. Should be better now

Answer (score 1):

Check here there is a find duplicates method in the comments that should solve your problem

[How do I remove repeated elements from ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203984/how-do-i-remove-repeated-elements-from-arraylist)

Answer (score 0):

idea(s) : use a map `Map<String, Integer>` that maps from word to occurance

Answer (score 0):

Another idea:

```
1. Create a set to store repeating items.
2. Create a set to store already seen items.
3. Begin loop to iterate around the array/list you have.
  3.1. If the current item is found in the already seen items set add it to repeating items set.
  3.2. Add the current item to already seen items set.
4. End loop.
```