# Removing Duplicates in ArrayList<MyItem> Android

Tags: android

ArrayList arReceipient = new ArrayList(); is declared globally. The arraylist is populated as follows

```
arReceipient.add(new MyItem(data.get(i).getId(),data.get(i).getNickName()));
```

Resulting in

```
sId 1000002327 sName htc1
sId 1000002208 sName htcandroid
sId 1000002208 sName htcandroid
sId 1000002242 sName htcandroid1
sId 1000000721 sName bachan
sId 1000000721 sName bachan
sId 1000000810 sName bachan2
```

How can i remove duplicates entries such that result is

```
 sId 1000002327 sName htc1
 sId 1000002208 sName htcandroid
 sId 1000002242 sName htcandroid1
 sId 1000000721 sName bachan
 sId 1000000810 sName bachan2
```

Here is MyItem class

```
public class MyItem {

    public String sId;
    public String sName;

    public MyItem(String sid, String sname){

        this.sId=sid;
        this.sName=sname;

    }

}
```

Comment: And then read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203984/how-do-i-remove-repeated-elements-from-arraylist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

HashSet hashmap = new HashSet();
hashmap.addAll(list);
list.clear();
list.addAll(hashmap);
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of list use `set`.

```
LinkedHashSet<MyItem> arReceipient =new LinkedHashSet<MyItem>();
```

and add equals method in `MyItem`

```
public class MyItem {

    public String sId;
    public String sName;

    public MyItem(String sid, String sname){

        this.sId=sid;
        this.sName=sname;

    }
   public boolean equals(Object o){
      if(!(o instanceof MyItem)) return false;
      return sId==((MyItem)o).sId;
  }

}
```

Comment: will it change the order of rows ?

Comment: if you want to preserve order, you can use LinkedHashSet instead

Comment: Thanks last thing what is the equivalent LinkedHashSet of arReceipient.get(x).sId