# Removing duplicates in an ArrayList using Generics

Tags: java, generics

I was asked to write a small program to remove the duplicates from a list and make a new list without the duplicates. We had to do this using Generics in Java. This is what I have so far:

**All help is greatly appreciated!!!**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Assignment13 {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("one");
    list.add("one");
    list.add("two");
    list.add("three");
    list.add("three");


    System.out.println("Prior to removal: " + list);
    System.out.println("after: " + list2);


}

public static <E> ArrayList<E> removeDuplicates(ArrayList<E> list) {

    ArrayList<E> list2 = new ArrayList<E>();

    for (int i = 1; i < list2.size(); i++) {
        String a1 = list2.get(i);
        String a2 = list2.get(i-1);
        if (a1.equals(a2)) {
            list2.remove(a1);
        }
    }


    return list2;

 }

}
```

Comment: You initialize an empty `list2` then try to iterate over it. Do you see a problem here?

Comment: There is a variety of answers to similar problems on SO. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/203992/4235784) for a brief yet elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

From your question it seems that there is no guarantee that duplicated elements in the original list must appear in sequence. This means that checking if two adjacent elements are equal is not sufficient to remove all duplicates.

Checking adjacent elements would work if the list was sorted. But since you need to use generics, I suppose you are not allowed to make assumptions about the nature of the elements. This means you cannot sort the list, because you would need to know that the elements were `Comparable`.

So you can do it like this:

```
1. Create a new empty list
2. For each element in the original list
    2.1 If the element is not in the new list, add it
    2.2 Else, ignore it
```

If you are allowed to use Java 8, this is much easier:

```
static <E> List<E> removeDuplicates(List<E> list) {
    return list.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the algorithm:

```
public static <E> ArrayList<E> removeDuplicates(ArrayList<E> list) {

    ArrayList<E> list2 = new ArrayList<E>();

    for (E elem : list) 
        if (!list2.contains(elem))
            list2.add(elem);

    return list2;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a loop and a condition:

```
public static <E> ArrayList<E> removeDuplicates(ArrayList<E> list) {
    ArrayList<E> list2 = new ArrayList<E>();

    for(E item : list) {
        if(!list2.contains(item)) {
            list2.add(item);
        }
    }

    return list2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a Set (if allowed in your assignment) is more efficient than checking list.contains on each item.  Ex:

```
public static <E> ArrayList<E> removeDuplicates(ArrayList<E> list) {
    Set<E> uniques = new HashSet<E>();
    uniques.addAll(list);
    return new ArrayList<E>(uniques);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The general strategy here is that you want to *maintain a context* as you traverse the list, and at each step, you use that piece of context to answer the question of whether the current item should be kept or thrown out.  In pseudo-code:

```
public static <A> List<A> removeDuplicates(List<? extends A> original) {
    List<A> result = new ArrayList<A>();

    /* initialize context */        

    for (A item : original) {
        if ( /* context says item is not a duplicate */ ) {
            result.add(item);
        }
        /* update context to incorporate the current `item` */
    }
    return result;
}
```

Some people have brought up the question of whether you mean consecutive duplicates or non-consecutive ones.  In reality, the difference in the solutions is small:

1. For consecutive duplicates the context is the most recently seen item.
2. For non-consecutive it's the `Set<A>` of all items seen up to that point.

I'll let you fill in the pattern for those cases.

Answer (score -1):

Updated for your question

```
 ArrayList<E> list2 = new ArrayList<E>();


    for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
        String a1 = list2.get(i);
        if (!list2.contains(a1)) {
            list2.add(a1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It does solve the initial problem, but does not solve the main question at hand

Comment: I tried to do that but it did not work. For some reason my for loop is not taking out the duplicates.

Comment: a) you didn't return list2, b) you made list2 a reference to list instead of copying the elements (therefore you will modify list by side effect).

Comment: @spudone i accidentally left list2 = list from before edit.. i have removed it

Comment: 1) `a1` is not a `String`, but a `E` 2) You are getting a object from a list and then are checking if the same list contains it.