# Remove duplicates from ArrayList<CustomClass> Android

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, duplicates

I just able to load songs from sdcard and get a list of their albums but it contains duplicates in it. How to remove duplicated from my album list. My Album list is a type of ArrayList and Album class contains two String variable in it.
thank you for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remove repeated elements from ArrayList?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203984/how-do-i-remove-repeated-elements-from-arraylist)

Comment: ... and of course ... it will not work ... obviously, it need one more thing ... something that would compare the items ...

Comment: It,s not a duplicate of that question. I can remove elements from ArrayList of predefined classes but my question is to make my list unique using custom class which contain more than one variables.

Comment: It is a duplicate ... but still you should know how Set compare the objects ... so take a look @petey answer ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your Custom class, add an equals and hashCode method,

```
public static class Custom
{
    public final String item1;
    public final String item2;
    public Custom(String i1, String i2) {
        item1 = i1;
        item2 = i2;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        Custom custom = (Custom) o;

        if (!item1.equals(custom.item1)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!item2.equals(custom.item2)) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = item1.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + item2.hashCode();
        return result;
    }

}
```

Then before adding, check that the Arraylist does not contain a Custom before adding.

```
final ArrayList<Custom> customs = new ArrayList<Custom>();
Custom one = new Custom("aa", "bb");
Custom two = new Custom("aa", "bb");

if (!customs.contains(one)) {
    arraylist.add(one);
}

if (!customs.contains(two)) {
    arraylist.add(two);
}
```

Comment: @Selvin  if this is working for you, can you accept the answer?

Comment: I can't ... I already know this ... and ... i didn't ask... :P ... ok, at least i could upvote :P