# I have a List of webelements. these webelements have duplicate text values. I want to print only the unique texts from the list of webelements

Tags: java, selenium

```
//retrieving a set of WebElement    

List <WebElement> discount =driver.findElements(By.className("saleD"));

for(int i=0;i<discount.size();i++)
{
     //getting text of webelements
     String disc_per= discount.get(i).getText();
     // Now I want that only unique texts to be stored. What can I do to get this.
}
System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: Please define your problem proper way.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203984/how-do-i-remove-repeated-elements-from-arraylist

Answer (score 0):

Convert the List to a Set , which will hold ONLY Unique values.

```
List<String> webElementText=  Store all (webElement.getText)
Set<String> uniquewebElementsText = new HashSet<String>(webElementText);
```

Now the `uniquewebElementsText` has all Unique entries.

Answer (score -1):

`List#contains()` method gives you if the list already has that element or not.

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
for(int i = 0; i < discount.size(); ++i)
{
 if(!list.contains(discount.get(i))
   list.add(discount.get(i));
}
System.out.println("No of unique elements are : " + list.size());
System.out.println(list);
```

---

Or you could use a `set`.

```
Set set = new Set();
for(int i = 0; i < discount.size(); ++i)
{
   set.add(discount.get(i));
}
```

Or a 1 liner.

```
Set<String> s = new LinkedHashSet<String>(list);
```