# How to find duplicats and display in List/ArrayList without using Set/Map implementation in java? Is it possible? Then how?

Tags: java

Give me with example to find duplicates and display in List/ArrayList without using Set/Map implementation in java? Is it possible? Then how?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not living in the Stone Age. We have "Google" to look for some things.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203984/how-do-i-remove-repeated-elements-from-arraylist

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's possible. The most obvious solution isn't very efficient, but it generates the right answer:

```
List<String> input = ...
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

for (String item : input) {
    if (!result.contains(item)) {
        result.add(item);
    }
}
```

But why would you want to do this? (Except perhaps to settle a stupid bet).

Comment: *Is it possible? Then how?* - I don't think he even tried looking for a solution :)