# Sort a list according to a property java

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have a list of Strings

```
ArrayList<String> titles = t1,t1,t2,t2,t3,t3,t3
```

I want a sublist with the unique values ie. `titles2 = t1,t2,t3`

How can I do this? Any help is appreciated

Comment: What's the relation between sorting and removing duplicates?

Comment: Plz paste your code correctly . ``ArrayList<String> titles = t1,t1,t2,t2,t3,t3,t3`` is not a valid code I guess

Comment: You can try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203984/how-do-i-remove-repeated-elements-from-arraylist

Comment: @ThanhDuyNgo your answer helped me . thanks

Comment: @helloworld: you're welcome

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)  which is :

> A collection that contains no duplicate elements.

And a [TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) for the sorting (if needed).

Example :

```
Set<String> set = new TreeSet<String>(list);
```