# Java - HashSet to filter duplicates(XSSFCell)

Tags: java, hashset, linkedhashset

I have a list which contains duplicates & need to remove them. My list is of the form

```
List<List<XSSFCell>> results;
```

A sample of data stored in the List 'results' is:

- [ABC, 123, 22-Apr-2016]
- [DEF, 456, 22-Apr-2016]
- [ABC, 123, 22-Apr-2016]
- [ABC, 123, 10-Jan-2016]

Based on this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203984/how-do-i-remove-repeated-elements-from-arraylist) I tried the below code:

```
Set<List<XSSFCell>> hashSetResults = new LinkedHashSet<>(results);
```

Expected output is:

- [ABC, 123, 22-Apr-2016]
- [DEF, 456, 22-Apr-2016]
- [ABC, 123, 10-Jan-2016]

But it is not removing the duplicate & the entire list gets saved in the Set. Hope am clear on the issue faced, seek guidance.

Comment: This is because because you are passing list of objects, how to fix it need a bit of thinking

Comment: Are the individual `XSSFCell` entries equal (using the `equals()` method)?  If the lists were actually equal (via `equals()`) I think your approach should work.

Comment: I checked the JavaDoc and an `XSSFCell` object has a row and column index.  So even though two cells in two lists might be logically equal, they can not be equal via `equals()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should override XSSFCell equal method.