# How to remove duplicate elements in ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I noticed that i return duplicate rows in my `listview` constructed from my `arrayList`. I would like to check if the elements exist in the `arraylist` and if so, ignore that set. The unique value to check would be my `id`, denoted by `KEY_SID`.

Here's my code:

```js
 public ArrayList<SaleModel> loadSalesFromSQLite() {
        ArrayList<SaleModel> sales = new ArrayList<>();
        hp = new HashMap();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_SALES + " ORDER BY datetime(created_at) DESC", null);
        res.moveToFirst();
        while (!res.isAfterLast()) {
            SaleModel l_sales = new SaleModel();

            l_sales.setId(res.getString(res
                    .getColumnIndex(KEY_SID)));
            l_sales.setCode(res.getString(res
                    .getColumnIndex(KEY_CODE)));
            l_sales.setAttendant_id(res.getString(res
                    .getColumnIndex(KEY_ATTENDANT_ID)));
            l_sales.setAttendant_name(res.getString(res
                    .getColumnIndex(KEY_ATTENDANT_NAME)));
            l_sales.setProduct_id(res.getString(res
                    .getColumnIndex(KEY_PRODUCT_ID)));
            l_sales.setPrice(res.getString(res
                    .getColumnIndex(KEY_PRICE)));
            l_sales.setCustomer_id(res.getString(res
                    .getColumnIndex(KEY_CUSTOMER_ID)));
            l_sales.setCustomer_first_name(res.getString(res
                    .getColumnIndex(KEY_CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME)));
            l_sales.setCustomer_last_name(res.getString(res
                    .getColumnIndex(KEY_CUSTOMER_LAST_NAME)));
            l_sales.setCustomer_image(res.getString(res
                    .getColumnIndex(KEY_CUSTOMER_IMAGE)));
            l_sales.setUid(res.getString(res
                    .getColumnIndex(KEY_UID)));
            l_sales.setQuantity(res.getString(res
                    .getColumnIndex(KEY_QUANTITY)));
            l_sales.setP_name(res.getString(res
                    .getColumnIndex(KEY_PRODUCT_NAME)));
            l_sales.setP_image(res.getString(res
                    .getColumnIndex(KEY_PRODUCT_IMAGE)));
            l_sales.setCreated_at(res.getString(res
                    .getColumnIndex(KEY_PRODUCT_CREATED)));
            l_sales.setSvg(res.getString(res
                    .getColumnIndex(KEY_SVG)));
            l_sales.setOfflineTag(res.getString(res
                    .getColumnIndex(KEY_OFFLINETAG)));

            sales.add(l_sales);
            res.moveToNext();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Fetching sales from Sqlite: ");
        res.close();
        return sales;
    }
```

Before i return `sales` `arrayList`, i would like to check for duplicates there, remove them, the return the `arrayList` without duplicates. Any suggestions?

Comment: This will sure help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203984/how-do-i-remove-repeated-elements-from-arraylist

Comment: [Already Answered Here on Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/203992/3535606)

Answer (score 0):

You could do a couple of things:

1. Use `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` in your SQL to remove duplicates coming back from the database
2. Add the elements to a `Set` instead of an `ArrayList` (but you would need to ensure your `SaleModel` class implments `hashCode()` and `equals()`

Answer (score 0):

With Lambda Expression

```
List<Object> newList = listWithDuplicates.stream()
                          .distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```