# Find all the years in a list of dates

Tags: java, android, list, date, java-time

So, I have a list of dates that is something like this:

```
List<String> dates = ["2012-05-16", "2012-05-18", "2012-06-19", "2013-01-18", "2013-01-10", "2013-08-05", "2010-07-10"...]
```

The list goes on with like 100 dates and I want to retrieve all the years that exists on the list. (to get a result like this)

```
List<String> years = ["2012", "2013", "2010"...]
```

Comment: Also add the code that you tried.

Comment: What language do you use? Java?

Comment: Yes, android studio uses java

Comment: Prerak, I didn't try any code because i coudn't think a way of doing this

Comment: Don’t use a list of `String` for your dates. Use `List<LocalDate>`. Just like you don’t store your numbers and Boolean values in strings (I hope).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a substring to split the first 4 characters of each item out. It will leave you with the year

```
   for (String s : dates) {
         String year = s.subString(0,5);
         years.add(year);

      }
```

or you could use the .split() method

```
String year =  s.split("-")[0];
```

**EDIT**

Upon further clarification, the question was to get unique years in the array list.

This can be done by passing the arraylist into a Set which does not accept duplicate values and then passing the set back into the array

```
// add elements to al, including duplicates
Set<String> hs = new HashSet<>();
hs.addAll(years);
years.clear();
years.addAll(hs);
```

From [How do I remove repeated elements from ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203984/how-do-i-remove-repeated-elements-from-arraylist)

Comment: Probably I wasn't clear on my question, I don't want repetition on my list, i want all years to be unique

Comment: Change years to a `Set` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html to guarantee uniqueness

Comment: @MateusDadalto Thanks for the clarification, check the edit.

Answer (score 1):

## `java.time`

I recommend you do it using the modern Date-Time API. Depending on your requirement, you can get the list of years in the form of `Integer`, `String`, `Year` etc.

**Demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> dates = List.of("2012-05-16", "2012-05-18", "2012-06-19", 
                "2013-01-18", "2013-01-10", "2013-08-05",   "2010-07-10");

        List<Integer> yearsIntList = 
                dates.stream()
                    .map(LocalDate::parse)
                    .map(d -> d.getYear())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

        List<String> yearsStrList =
                dates.stream()
                    .map(LocalDate::parse)
                    .map(d -> String.valueOf(d.getYear()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

        List<Year> yearsYearList = 
                dates.stream()
                    .map(LocalDate::parse)
                    .map(d -> Year.of(d.getYear()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(yearsIntList);
        System.out.println(yearsStrList);
        System.out.println(yearsYearList);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[2012, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2010]
[2012, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2010]
[2012, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2010]
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/WY1uSK)

Note that all of your date strings are in the ISO 8601 format. The modern Date-Time API is based on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and does not require using a `DateTimeFormatter` object explicitly as long as the Date-Time string conforms to the ISO 8601 standards.

Learn more about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

### Note:

Use `.distinct()` before collecting the `Stream` if you need a unique collection of years e.g.

```
List<String> yearsStrList = 
    dates.stream()
        .map(LocalDate::parse)
        .map(d -> String.valueOf(d.getYear()))
        .distinct()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Output:**

```
[2012, 2013, 2010]
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/v8TkOc)

---

<sup>* If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table). Note that Android 8.0 Oreo already provides [support for `java.time`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

you can check for duplicates before adding into a list (or you can use a Set instead of a List).

```
   for (String date : dates) {
         String year = date.substring(0,5);
         if(!years.contain(year)){
             years.add(year); 
         }else{
             //already in the list
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> years = dates.stream()
    .map(x -> x.substring(0, 4))
    .distinct()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

- For each entry you take just the first 4 characters (you could even parse the string into a date and then you just get the year)
- After that you take each value distinctly (no duplicates)
- And you collect that stream into a List