# Avoiding adding duplicate objects to an ArrayList

Tags: java, class, arraylist, duplicates

Here's the gist, essentially I have this method right with the exception of one conditional that I just can't seem to get. The condition is that if `addGame()` is called twice with the same two Strings it will not store the `Game` object in the `games` ArrayList since it will return false. I have already attempted to utilize the ArrayList `contains()` method to fix it, but the JUnit test I created fails each time. Here's the code for the method:

```
public class Conference {


    private ArrayList<Team> teams;
    private ArrayList<Player> players;
    private ArrayList<Game> games;
    public Conference(){
        teams = new ArrayList<Team>();
        players = new ArrayList<Player>();
        games = new ArrayList<Game>();
    }
public boolean addGame(String team1, String team2) {
      Game tempgame = new Game(team1, team2, 0, 0);
      Team first = new Team(team1, 0, 0, 0);
      Team second = new Team(team2, 0, 0, 0);
      if(!tempgame.getFirst().equals(tempgame.getSecond())){
          games.add(tempgame);
          first.addGamesPlayed();
          second.addGamesPlayed();
          teams.add(first);
          teams.add(second);
       return true;
      }
      return false;
}
```

The `Game` class is as follows:

```
package conference;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Game {
    private String firstTeam;
    private String secondTeam;
    private int firstTeamGoals;
    private int secondTeamGoals;
    private ArrayList<Team> team;
    public Game(String first, String second, int goals1, int goals2){
        this.firstTeam = first;
        this.secondTeam = second;
        this.firstTeamGoals = goals1;
        this.secondTeamGoals = goals2;
        team = new ArrayList<Team>();
    }
    public String getFirst(){
        return new String(firstTeam);
    }
    public String getSecond(){
        return new String(secondTeam);
    }
    public int getFirstTeamGoals(){
        return this.firstTeamGoals;
    }
    public int addFirstTeamGoals(){
        return firstTeamGoals++;
    }
    public int getSecondTeamGoals(){
        return this.secondTeamGoals;
    }
    public int addSecondTeamGoals(){
        return secondTeamGoals++;
    }
    public boolean hasMatchup(String t1, String t2){
        if(this.firstTeam.equals(t1) && this.secondTeam.equals(t2)){
            return true;
        }
        if(this.firstTeam.equals(t2) && this.secondTeam.equals(t1)){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And the `Team` class:

```
package conference;

public class Team {


    private String teamName;
    private int goalsScored;
    private int gamesPlayed;
    private int gamesWon;
    public Team(String name, int totalGoals, int games, int wins){
    this.teamName = name;
    this.goalsScored = totalGoals;
    this.gamesPlayed = games;
    this.gamesWon = wins;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return new String(teamName);
    }
    public int getTotalGoals(){
        return goalsScored;
    }
    public int addGoals(){
        return goalsScored++;
    }
    public int addGamesPlayed(){
        return this.gamesPlayed++;
    }
    public int getGamesPlayed(){
        return gamesPlayed;
    }
    public int addGamesWon(){
        return gamesWon++;
    }
    public int getGamesWon(){
        return gamesWon;
    }
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        } else if (obj == this) {
            return true;
        } else {
            if (!(obj instanceof Team)) {
                return false;
            } else {
                Team temp = (Team) obj;
                return this.teamName.equals(temp.getName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it that you cannot store the same two strings *ever* or is it that you cannot store the same two strings in a row?

Comment: Can't store the same two strings ever

Comment: The strings are stored in a game object, that's why I can't have two of the same objects stored in the ArrayList ever

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove repeated elements from ArrayList?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203984/how-do-i-remove-repeated-elements-from-arraylist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method is likely failing because though the strings aren't equal, that doesn't mean that the `teams` or `games` list don't *already have* those strings. You need to loop over the games list and check if the name equals `team1` or `team2`, if so, return false.

It's good that you compare the given teams aren't the same, and you can use your parameters to compare, but that's not the only condition you need.

```
if(!team1.equals(team2)) {
```

Also, the fact you have `new String` on values that are already strings makes a new object in memory, (therefore it's pointless) but the equals method should still work.

Comment: Should also note this is to protect against identical pairings

Comment: Right. And that is fine, you just haven't checked if `games`or `teams` already has `team1` or `team2`

Answer (score 0):

"The strings are stored in a game object, that's why I can't have two of the same objects stored in the ArrayList ever" (Your comment.)

It seems that in exchange for more memory you could use a `Set` (`HashSet` or `TreeSet`) to store records of previous games played. If you're protecting against identical pairings rather than identical team names (at any point), sort the two `String` team names consistently and concatenate them into a key. Check whether that key already exists in the set.

EDIT: See the other solution for `ArrayList` only.

Comment: Ah, forgot one thing to mention, another constraint is I can only use ArrayList, Math and String classes.

Comment: @yarcenahs *snap* ah well that's the way I would have done it. :) I guess this can be for personal "extra credit".