# How to get duplicate objects on ArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, java-8

I'm facing a problem in Java... I have one list of object `Objeto`, this object has the attributes listed below:

```
public class Objeto{
    private FirstEntity first;
    private List<ThirdEntity> thirds;
}
```

I need to find the objects in this list that have the same `FirstEntity` attribute... How can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Override `equals()` method in the object.

Comment: What have you tried? You've got to put forth a little effort. Are instances of `FirstEntity` realy the "same" or do they just have the same contents?

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider they just have the "same" content

Comment: @PritamBanerjee how do you sugest to override equals?

Comment: @PritamBanerjee I would not recommend overriding equals() when you do not know exactly what you do since many methods rely on this method!

Comment: Do you have FirstEntity object to compare with the attributes from the list? Or you want to find all coinsidents from the list without any template FirstEntity object?

Comment: do you want to remove those objects or collect them in some list? For removing you could see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203984/how-do-i-remove-repeated-elements-from-arraylist/203992#203992

Comment: @VasiliyVlasov I want to find all coinsidents from the list without any template...

Answer (score 3):

The main reason why this question is difficult to answer, is because we don't know how many possible values there are for `FirstEntity` to hold.  For this reason, we must use a `Map<FirstEntity, List<Objecto>>` where, for every `FirstEntity`, we store a `List<Objecto>` that share the `FirstEntity` attribute.

For this to compile, you must create a getter in your `Objecto` class for `FirstEntity`:

```
public FirstEntity getFirstEntity() {
    return first;
}
```

Then, the `List<Objecto>` can be streamed and collected into a `Map<FirstEntity, List<Objecto>>`:

```
Map<FirstEntity, List<Objecto>> map = thirds.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Objecto::getFirstEntity));
```

For this to work, you must override `Object#equals` and `Object#hashCode` within `FirstEntity`.

Comment: Thanks! But I cannot remove the elements... I have to edit the duplicated elements...

Comment: You're welcome!  I've edited my post to accommodate that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But that's not the right object... I've edited my question to illustrate better... Thanks! =)

Comment: OH that makes more sense, I'll fix it again!

Answer (score 2):

(As before, if you need to use Java 7 or earlier - and same discussion re. FirstEntity hashCode() and equals() as in the other answer).

Assuming we have

```
 List<Objecto> myObjectos;
```

Then the following should work:

```
 Map<FirstEntity, List<Objecto>> map = new HashMap<>();
 for(Objecto objecto : myObjectos){
       if(!map.containsKey(objecto.first)){
              map.put(objecto.first, new LinkedList<Objecto>());
       }
       map.get(objecto.first).add(objecto);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But that's not the right object... I've edited my question to illustrate better... Thanks! =)

Comment: Not sure I understand - are you asking, for all Objectos on a List, L, which of them have a first which is another Objecto (on the list) already has?  Or are you asking to "group" all Objecto's which share "first"?

Comment: If you don't need objetos with unique attribute, just remove from the map all keys with values of size < 2.

Comment: @dan.mwasuser2321368 your code in for loop can be simplified to:`map.computeIfAbsent(objecto.first, (key)-> new LinkedList<>()).add(objecto)`

Comment: @holi-java my answer explicitly states that it is for the case where the user is limited to Java 7. Jacob G,'s answer contains a Java 8 solution.