# Write a for loop for a sequence by skipping for value there in a list?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have list of integer and I want create a for loop from sequence 1 to n skipping the elements which are already there in the List, So which is the best way or efficient way to do?

Comment: You can find a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203984/how-do-i-remove-repeated-elements-from-arraylist

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove repeated elements from ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203984/how-do-i-remove-repeated-elements-from-arraylist)

Comment: What does this question have to do with `hibernate` or `spring-mvc`?

Answer (score 1):

Most *efficient* way, i.e. *O(m+n)*, is to convert the `List` to a [`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html), then check using [`contains()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#contains-java.lang.Object-):

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>(list);
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    if (! set.contains(i)) {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

If you don't convert to `Set`, and use the `contains()` method of `List` directly, performance would be *O(mn)*, where *m* is number of elements in the list.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

You can use hashset for the purpose it will automatically remove the repeated elements. So for your input array, put each element one by one in the hashset and at the end your hashset will contain the non repeated elements.

On doubts regarding hashshet refer: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_hashset_class.htm

Comment: Question is not about removing duplicates from list. It's about a `for` loop, *skipping* values already in a list.

Comment: To say exactly, you skip for only if there is a repeated value , which means there is a duplicate for a value. Internally Hashset uses contains method to check whether the input is present or not

Comment: There is nothing in the question saying that the loop will modify the list. If list is `[2, 4, 5]` and `n = 7`, OP simply wants a loop that iterates the values `1`, `3`, `6`, and `7`. There are no "duplicates" in any of that.