# How to iterate over items of list and delete duplicated ones while remain the original order?

Tags: java

Note: This question is for my assignment. So there are some rules which might seem to be not normal.

I just realized my question before doesn't make sense. So I edited it.

Assume that I have a list containing integers [1,2,3,4,1,2,1,5]

By using an iterator, how can I remove duplicated items while keeping the order of items undisrupted?

The expected result for above list should be [1,2,3,4,5]
And contain() method is not allowed to use.

What I currently came up with is the same as what Manash Ranjan Dakua answered in this question
[How do I remove repeated elements from ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203984/how-do-i-remove-repeated-elements-from-arraylist)

```
public static void main(String[] args){
ArrayList<Object> al = new ArrayList<Object>();
al.add("abc");
al.add('a');
al.add('b');
al.add('a');
al.add("abc");
al.add(10.3);
al.add('c');
al.add(10);
al.add("abc");
al.add(10);
System.out.println("Before Duplicate Remove:"+al);
for(int i=0;i<al.size();i++){
    for(int j=i+1;j<al.size();j++){
        if(al.get(i).equals(al.get(j))){
            al.remove(j);
            j--;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println("After Removing duplicate:"+al);
```

}

But if I wish to use Iterator instead of for loops here? How can I achieve that(remove duplicated items while keeping order unchanged)?

If the question is not clear enough or too vague. Pls point out! I'll try to rephrase it.

Thanks for help!

Comment: I'm unclear on what you're asking. Why not simply use the iterator that you currently have?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels You are right I didn't put my question clear enough

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Well, rules set by course assignment....have to use Iterators

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use `Iterator` to achieve that. A simple way is using [LinkedHashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) which allows to contain unique elements only like `HashSet` (*No Duplicates*) and **maintains** insertion order.

Example:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,1,2,1,5));
Set<Integer> set = new LinkedHashSet<>();
set.addAll(list);
// or as suggested by assylias, Set<Integer> set = new LinkedHashSet<>(list);
System.out.println(list);
System.out.println(set);
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Or simply `Set<Integer> set = new LinkedHashSet<>(list);` and `Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,1,2,1,5)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call .next() again which will allow you to move on to the next element in the array.  However if you want to get a new iterator for the rest of the elements, it would be best for you to use .next() through the rest of the list you have, adding each element to a new data structure and then call .iterator() on that new data structure.