# Compare two integers doesn't work correctly in Android

Tags: java, android, arraylist, compare

I have a method that have to compare an integer with an Arraylist and if the number on the integer is on the arraylist, I recieve a false. If the integer number is not on the arraylist I recieve a true.

I need this, because I'm making a quiz game that have some questions on a BBDD and I can't show the same question twice. Also this questions are in three categories: E, I and A. I have to show five E questions, then five I questions and then five A questions.

So I have to show questions without repeat them, and also 5 of each category. I make this methods but I don't know why it repeats some questions.

The only thing works correctly is the category questions. I have always 5 E questions, then 5 I questions and at least 5 A questions.

The method that told me if the questions is on the ArrayList:

```
private boolean checkRandom()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < listRandom.size(); i++)
    {
        if(questionPosition == listRandom.get(i))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

I also try with "equals", but I have the same result.

The method that check if the question is in the correct category and is not showed before:

```
private void loadPhase() {

    if (numQuestion < 15)
    {
        r = new Random();
        questionPosition = r.nextInt(listQuestions.size());

        if(numQuestion < 5)
        {
            while(!listPhase.get(questionPosition).equals("E") && (!listPhase.get(questionPosition).equals("E")|| !checkRandom()))
            {
                r = new Random();
                questionPosition = r.nextInt(listQuestions.size());
            }
        }
        else if(numQuestion > 4 && numQuestion < 10)
        {
            while(!listPhase.get(questionPosition).equals("I") && (!listPhase.get(questionPosition).equals("I")|| !checkRandom()))
            {
                r = new Random();
                questionPosition = r.nextInt(listQuestions.size());
            }
        }
        else if(numQuestion > 9)
        {
            while(!listPhase.get(questionPosition).equals("A") && (!listPhase.get(questionPosition).equals("A")|| !checkRandom()))
            {
                r = new Random();
                questionPosition = r.nextInt(listQuestions.size());
            }
        }

        listRandom.add(questionPosition);

        header4questions.setText(listQuestions.get(questionPosition));

        answer1.setText(listAnswers.get(questionPosition * 4));
        answer2.setText(listAnswers.get((questionPosition * 4) + 1));
        answer3.setText(listAnswers.get((questionPosition * 4) + 2));
        answer4.setText(listAnswers.get((questionPosition * 4) + 3));

        numQuestion++;
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have finished the quiz!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        uploadPoints();
    }
}
```

So, what I have is all the questions on the correct category, but it repeat the questions and I don't know why.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: You really need to debug this code to find out the error.

Comment: To pick `n` questions at random from a `List` without replacement, use `Collections.shuffle` to shuffle the list and then just take the first `n` items from it.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem what do you mean with get(iny) is different from get(object)? is that my error?

Comment: No, I'm entirely wrong, so I've unthumped the question. I'm going to have to study your question more carefully.

Comment: ok, I wait @DawoodibnKareem Thanks a lot!

Comment: Change while condition with following:
 `while(!listPhase.get(questionPosition).equals("E") && checkRandom() && !listPhase.get(questionPosition).equals("E"))`

Comment: @ShayanPourvatan with this, I have questions of category A before they have to appear. I need five E, five I and five A. Also it repeat the questions. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your return as below

```
private boolean checkRandom()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < listRandom.size(); i++)
    {
        if(questionPosition == listRandom.get(i))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I try. Wait! :)

Comment: As in question said: _if the number on the integer is on the arraylist, I recieve a false_ so, it's fine the way it is now!!

Comment: As you see in the question, I recieve a false if the integer is on the arraylist, and in the other method, when I call checkRandom, I call it with that "!checkRandom()". The exclamation check is for this false value that I want to recieve if the integer is on the arraylist. I try with your answer and it doesn't work.

Comment: I thing Best way is to use Collection class and use Binary search the Id to check if exist, will be more efficient

Answer (score 0):

Although converting the `ArrayList` to a `HashSet` effectively removes duplicates, if you need to preserve insertion order, I'd rather suggest you use this variant

```js
list is some List of Strings
Set < String > s = new LinkedHashSet < > (list);
```

Then, if you need to get back a `List` reference, you can use again the conversion constructor.

Answer reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/204004/8252521

Answered by user: https://stackoverflow.com/users/27565/abahgat

Comment: I don't have duplicates, I mean... I have a random number that is compared with the ArrayList that have the questions, but the ArrayList doesn't have duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it! I have to change the while condition like this:

```
while(!listPhase.get(questionPosition).equals("E") || (listPhase.get(questionPosition).equals("E") && !checkRandom()))
```