# removing duplicate values from sql table added in arraylist

Tags: java, mysql

I want to remove duplicate values from array list i.e String which has been updated from MySQL

[image]

Comment: you can check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203984/how-do-i-remove-repeated-elements-from-arraylist

Answer (score 1):

First check the query if you can eliminate duplicate values from the query itself. Even if you can't , then use LinkedHashMap.

Answer (score 0):

As its a String, you can use Set data structure to hold these values, which doesn't contain the duplicate values.

Read more about set [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html).

Sample code of HashSet :-

```
public class SetEx {

public static void main(String args[])
{
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
    set.add("abc");
    set.add("aaa");
    set.add("fgh");
    set.add("hdsjkadhka");
    set.add("abc");
    set.add("aaa");

    System.out.println("set of Strings " + set);
}
```

}

Edit :- if you want to create a HashSet from existing ArrayList then use below code :-

```
 ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("amit");
        list.add("amit");

        Set<String> copySet = new HashSet<>(list);

        System.out.println("set of string "+ copySet);
```

Comment: can you give a sample code bro please am new to java

Comment: yes I cannot paste my code , it shows please add some context to explain, am doing but still not allowed to submit question  can you contact me on whatsapp

Comment: @viralvathas , please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , you will be able to paste your code after your read this.

Comment: @viralvathas , I also added the code in my Edit, where you can create set using existing array-list.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use LinkedHashSet, which store only unique data i.e no duplicate data allow in LinkedHashSet.
also,it store data in same sequence as ArrayList.

or use this code-

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

// add elements to list, including duplicates

Set<String> hs = new LinkedHashSet<>();

hs.addAll(list);

list.clear();

list.addAll(hs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Java 8 `Streams`**:

```
List<String> listWithDups = getListWithDupes();
//do something else before remove dupes
List<String> result = listWithDups.stream()
    .distinct()
    .collect(Collector.toList());
//Use your new list
```

Also, if you obtain duplicated values from your `SQL` query, you should consider using `DISTINCT` keyword in your query.