# addedprogram in android to remove duplicates in ArrayList<obj>

Tags: android, arrays, iterator

I am new to android
I am writing a program to remove duplicates in ArrayList

The program is as follows

```
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
                        it = iterator;
                        //it.next();
                        while (it.hasNext()) {
                            it.next();
                            if (it.equals(iterator)) {
                                it.remove();
                                //it.next();
                            }
                        }
                        iterator.next();
                    }
```

but it crashes.
Can someone give mesomeinput?

error log->

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                   Process: com.example.root.securityalert, PID: 23735
>                                                                                   java.util.NoSuchElementException
>                                                                                       at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:834)
>                                                                                       at
>   com.example.root.securityalert.DeviceScanActivity$1.run(DeviceScanActivity.java:113)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6165)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                       at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)

I also used

```
    List newList = new ArrayList(new LinkedHashSet(arrayOfUsers2));
    Iterator<ViewHolder> it=newList.iterator();
                        while(it.hasNext()) {
                            ViewHolder currentX = it.next();
                            adapter.add(currentX);
                        }
public class ViewHolder {
        String deviceName;
        String deviceAddress;

        public ViewHolder(String device, String __address) {
            this.deviceName =device;
            this.deviceAddress= __address;
        }
    }
```

but list has duplicates

I added the following code to ViewHolder class

```
@Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
            ViewHolder a = (ViewHolder) o;
            return Objects.equals(deviceAddress, a.deviceAddress);
        }
```

and 
added the code

```
if(!arrayOfUsers2.contains(newUser))
  arrayOfUsers2.add(newUser);
```

when new device is pushed into arraylist and now it is fine

Comment: Use `HashSet/Hashmap`.

Comment: you should provide the error that is crashing this code

Comment: I am using adapters for listview,so, I am using Arraylist

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove repeated elements from ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203984/how-do-i-remove-repeated-elements-from-arraylist)

Comment: You're using it.next() 2 times in the loop, this means that on the last element, you might call it twice, which cause the NoSuchElement, as calling next() on the last element can't be done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to run loop iterator inside another loop of iterator for this.
And in your code you are checking for equality two iteratos `if (it.equals(iterator))` Why? :)

Anyway, I think such solution could be done with this:

```
Iterator<Object> iterator = list.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Object i = iterator.next();
    if (list.contains(i)) {
        int index = list.indexOf(i);
        int lastIndex = list.lastIndexOf(i);

        if (index != lastIndex) {
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

In order to make this solution work, your objects should implement `equals` method.
For example, if you need to check only `deviceAddress` in your `ViewHolder` class, you should implement `equals` method like this:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    A a = (A) o;
    return Objects.equals(deviceAddress, a.deviceAddress);
}
```

Comment: it is not  removing duplicate entries. Is there anyway we can compare the address field which lies inside ViewHolder?

Comment: As I added to my answer your object must implement `equals`.

Comment: where should I put the equals method? will it be a part of ViewHolderclass?

Comment: Yes, it should be inside the `ViewHolder.class`.

Answer (score 0):

To remove duplicate in array you can use this kind of trick :

`List newList = new ArrayList(new LinkedHashSet(yourArrayList));`

The trick is to use a `set`, since it can't have duplicate values it will ommit them. Then you can create a new array from it

Using `LinkedHashSet` will keep the order

Comment: It  did not remove duplicates.I have pasted the code

Comment: Are you sure it's really duplicate, it has to be exactly the same. If it's complex objects a small diff makes all the differents. It should work

Comment: If you have ViewHolder duplicate I think you should try to fix it before. You should not have duplicate view holder in the first place. It's against the patern ^^ Also what is the point of having to manipulate an array of viewholder ?

Comment: it is a bluetoothscanner and scans samedevice multiple times

Comment: Ok but the viewholder pattern is a pattern strongly binded to the ListView or any view you are using. You should clean and sort your data before passing it to the View. The Viewholder list should just have to be displayed