# Search for duplicates by fields' value of objects type <T> in list<T>

Tags: java

I am not sure if my question is clear but I am trying to find duplicate objects inside a list where they are duplicates if they have 1 or more fields inside the object that has the same value. I am also trying to make it generic and reusable for many data classes.

Here is a solution that I just came up with. It returns true if it finds duplicate and else false.
Is this solution good? Or is there anything else I can use to achieve my goal?

(Edited to ignore null values)

```
public class TestObject {
    private String str;

    public TestObject(String str){
      this.str = str;
    }
}

public static <T> boolean checkForDuplicateByFields(List<T> ls, String... fieldNames) {
    if (ls == null || ls.isEmpty()) {
      return false;
    }

    //create hashset of <fieldName, values>
    HashMap<String, HashSet<Object>> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (String name : fieldNames) {
      map.put(name, new HashSet<>());
    }

    // Search for duplicates of fields' value in list <T>
    for (String name : fieldNames) {
      try {
        Field f = ls.get(0).getClass().getDeclaredField(name);
        f.setAccessible(true);
        for (T obj : ls) {
          try {
            HashSet<Object> names = map.get(name);
            Object o = f.get(obj);
            if(o == null){
              continue;
            }
            if (names.isEmpty()) {
              names.add(o);
            } else if (names.contains(o)) {
              return true;
            }
          } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            break;
          }
        }
      } catch (NoSuchFieldException ex) {
        break;
      }
    }
    return false;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    List<TestObject> ls = new ArrayList<>();
    TestObject obj = new TestObject("hello");
    ls.add(obj);
    ls.add(obj);
    System.out.println(checkForDuplicateByFields(ls, "str"));

}
```

Comment: Why can't you just override equals and hashcode to remove duplicate (If requirement is not more than that). This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51487805/how-to-implement-hashcode-and-equals-method-to-remove-duplicates-from-arraylist

Comment: I would consider it cleaner if you would create interfaces for the fields in question and have the classes implement the interfaces (or not) then you could simply check by `instanceOf` or `assignableFrom`.

Comment: @Swarit Agarwal the goal is to make it generic and you can search by as many fields as you want. By doing this, you dont have to override equals and hashcode everytime you try to do the same thing for different classes

Comment: Indeed, please update your question, as it needs to be generic approach, while you don't need equals and hashcode mechanism. It would be easy for other to answer :)

Comment: @Nicktar I am trying to compare by value. instanceOf and assignableFrom compare their types I think

Comment: @SwaritAgarwal, will do. Thanks

Comment: @RukaDo missed that... But still... simply put a default implementation of a method comparing the values of two instances of the interface and be good. Unfortunately you can't call this method equals because you can't override a method (equals from object) with a default implementation in an interface.

Comment: @Nicktar so are you saying your method won't solve what I am trying to achieve because of being unable to do method override (equals())

Comment: @RukaDo No, I'm just saying, you can't call your equals-method equals but have to come up with another name.

Comment: @RukaDo Please check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider you have getter method for each field, I think you could accomplish this using lambda and functional interface in a cleaner way.
Consider the following example:

```
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
         Student s = new Student(100,"xyz");
         Function<Student,Integer> studentRNMapper = ((student) -> student.getRollNumber());
         System.out.println(studentRNMapper.apply(s)); // print 100

         Function<Student,String> studentNameMapper = ((student) -> student.getName());
         System.out.println(studentNameMapper.apply(s)); // print "xyz"
    }
}

class Student {

    private Integer rollNumber;
    private String name;
    public Student(Integer rollNumber,String name) {
        this.rollNumber = rollNumber;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getRollNumber() {
        return rollNumber;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

}
```

Instead of passing field name, You could consider passing functional interface.This way you wont have to use reflection API.
In you case, It would look like this:

```
TestObject obj = new TestObject("hello");
ls.add(obj);
ls.add(obj);
Function<TestObject,String> testStrMapper = ((TestObject) -> TestObject.getStr());
System.out.println(checkForDuplicateByFields(ls, testStrMapper);
```

In your checkForDuplicateByFields, you would retrieve the value as follow:

```
testStrMapper.supply(ls.get(i)) <-- Return value of str field for the ith object.
```

Comment: will this be null-safe (will ignore null) and do I have to create a fucntional interface for each field?

Comment: @RukaDo Functional interface is already inbuilt in Java. You only need get a instace of it for the field you want to operate using following syntax "Function<TestObject,String> testStrMapper = ((TestObject) -> TestObject.getStr())"

Comment: testStrMapper.supply(testObject) will return null if value of your field is null.