# How to remove duplicate elements in a array using freemarker?

Tags: html, netsuite, freemarker

I had written the code for finding duplicate elements in C but now I am stuck at implementing the same code in freemarker Can anyone help?

```
int n, a[10], b[10], count = 0, c, d;

   printf("Enter number of elements in array\n");
   scanf("%d",&n);

   printf("Enter %d integers\n", n);
   for(c=0;c<n;c++)
      scanf("%d",&a[c]);

   for(c=0;c<n;c++)
   {
      for(d=0;d<count;d++)
      {
         if(a[c]==b[d])
            break;
      }
      if(d==count)
      {
         b[count] = a[c];
         count++;
      }
   }

   printf("Array obtained after removing duplicate elements\n");         
   for(c=0;c<count;c++)
      printf("%d\n",b[c]);
```

Comment: One tag is C, the code seems C. But freemarker is a java thing, isn't it? Are you porting this C->java? Or trying to use a java engine from C?

Comment: I needed to implement this logic in netsuite advanced pdf templates

Comment: See  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203984/how-do-i-remove-repeated-elements-from-arraylist

Comment: The root of the problem is that FreeMarker is not really a programming language... it's a template language. Think of printf but much more powerful. So, if the data-model content itself can't be changed, can you at least add some helper Java classes there? The template can pull in and instantiate such classes itself, they only have to exist in your "classpath" somehow.

Comment: @ddekany but still we can implement this no??

Comment: @marg It can be implemented inside the template, but it can get really slow, as the template language doesn't have true mutable lists.

Answer (score 9):

You can use freemarker sequences. Probably not super efficient but I've used this to group close to max size lines on invoices and such.

```
<#assign seen_style = []>
<#list record.item?sort_by("custcol_stylesort")  as lineitem>
   <#assign groupId = lineitem.item>
   <#if seen_style?seq_contains(groupId)> <!-- no if body is intentional; skips seen style -->
   <#else>
     <#assign seen_style = seen_style + [groupId]>
     <p>Do something with ${groupId}</p>
   </#if>
</#list>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new list without duplicates, using `seq_contains`.

```js
<#assign newList = [] />
<#list response.data.items as originalList>
    <#if ! newList?seq_contains(originalList.xValue)>
        <#assign newList = newList + [originalList.xValue] />
    </#if>
</#list>
```

[Original source](https://gist.github.com/juanbrusco/219105c2bb146e61313c9a60a968be93)

Comment: This is the exact same answer given in 2018, but the ! (not) syntax is helpful too.