# how can we remove multiple values in arrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, removeall

**remove** method we used for single remove, but I want to delete multiple values in array List.

```
ArrayList<Integer> al=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    al.add(7);
    al.add(8);
    al.add(9);
    al.add(13);
    al.add(22);
    al.add(55);
    al.add(88);
    //adding values
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
        al.add(i);
    }
```

I added duplicate elements, I want to fetch the duplicate elements and remove it from arraylist

for example:

output like:1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100

Comment: If you don't want duplicates, why not use a `Set`?

Comment: yeah but i want duplicate elements. that elements not present in my output

Comment: Why are you doing this? (i.e. what is the bigger picture) and will you always know the range you want? (i.e. 1 to 100)

Comment: A possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203984/how-do-i-remove-repeated-elements-from-arraylist

Comment: @ shanbhagsv   i didn't get answer in that so i asked here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use two `ArrayList`s, one with objects to remove and use [removeAll method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection)):

> Removes from this list all of its elements that are contained in the specified collection.

```
ArrayList<Integer> toRemove=new ArrayList<>();//use diamond operator to reduce verbosity 
toRemove.add(7);
toRemove.add(8);
toRemove.add(9);
toRemove.add(13);
toRemove.add(22);
toRemove.add(55);
toRemove.add(88);
ArrayList<Integer> al=new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
    al.add(i);
}
al.removeAll(toRemove);
```

Comment: can u explain briefly

Comment: @Venkatesh added more details, one list holds objects to remove and the full list remove all the objects using `removeAll` method

Comment: @  user7294900 Thankyou

Answer (score 2):

```
ArrayList<Integer> al=new ArrayList<Integer>();     
ArrayList<Integer> remove=new ArrayList<Integer>();   
al.add(7);   
al.add(8);   
al.add(9);   
al.add(13);     
al.add(22);   
al.add(55);  
al.add(88);  
remove.add(7);   
remove.add(8);   
remove.add(9);   
remove.add(13);   
remove.add(22);   
remove.add(55);   
remove.add(88);   
//adding values   
for(int i=0;i<100;i++){   
    al.add(i);   
}   
al.removeAll(remove);  
System.out.println(al);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<Integer> withoutDuplicates = new ArrayList<>(new HashSet<>(al));
```

Does not affect the original list with duplicates, which is what you seem to be asking for. If you do not care about the structure used for the second collection you could just keep it as a Set without creating another ArrayList.

Comment: "i want fetch the duplicate elements and remove it from arraylist" -> I'm confused, you asked here to remove duplicate elements, did you mean to remove BOTH values if more than one for a given number exists?

Answer (score 0):

Make use of streams to get distinct value. However i still believe Sets perfectly suit this scenario.

```
    ArrayList<Integer> al=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        al.add(7);
        al.add(8);
        al.add(9);
        al.add(13);
        al.add(22);
        al.add(55);
        al.add(88);

    List<Integer> list = al.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(list);
```