# Will parallel stream work fine with distinct operation?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I was reading about statelessness and came across this in [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Statelessness):

> Stream pipeline results may be nondeterministic or incorrect if the
>   behavioral parameters to the stream operations are stateful. A
>   stateful lambda (or other object implementing the appropriate
>   functional interface) is one whose result depends on any state which
>   might change during the execution of the stream pipeline.

Now if I have the a list of string (`strList` say) and then trying to remove duplicate strings from it using parallel streams in the following way:

```
List<String> resultOne = strList.parallelStream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or in case we want case insensitive:

```
List<String> result2 = strList.parallelStream().map(String::toLowerCase)
                       .distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Can this code have any problem as parallel streams will split the input and distinct in one chunk does not necessarily mean distinct in the whole input?

### EDIT (Quick summary of the answers below)

The `distinct` is a stateful operation and in case of stateful intermediate operations parallel streams may require multiple passes or substantial buffering overheads. Also `distinct` can be implemented more efficiently if ordering of elements is not relevant.
Also as per [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct--):

> For ordered streams, the selection of distinct elements is stable (for
>   duplicated elements, the element appearing first in the encounter
>   order is preserved.) For unordered streams, no stability guarantees
>   are made.

But in case of ordered stream running in parallel distinct may be unstable - means it will keep  an arbitrary element in case of duplicates and not necessarily the first one as expected from `distinct` otherwise.

From the [link](https://stuartmarks.wordpress.com/2015/01/09/writing-stateful-stream-operations/):

> Internally, the distinct() operation keeps a Set that contains
>   elements that have been seen previously, but it’s buried inside the
>   operation and we can’t get to it from application code.

So in case of parallel streams it would probably consume the entire stream or may use CHM (sth like `ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet()`). And for ordered ones most likely it would be using `LinkedHashSet` or similar contruct.

Comment: Only problem I can think of is that the order of the strings may different than the initial order in the `strList`

Comment: There's a hint in the apiNote of `Stream#distinct`: "**@apiNote**:
Preserving stability for distinct() in parallel pipelines is relatively expensive (requires that the **operation act as a full barrier, with substantial buffering overhead**)". And the same can be asked about reduction operations too (through parallel reduction is more easily conceivable than this `distinct` operation)

Comment: The quoted text is about *lambdas*, and `distinct()` doesn't take a lambda, so the quoted text is irrelevant. Also, if you **read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`distinct()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct--), you will see that it fully addresses the behavior of the method in *parallel* pipelines. The only problem is *performance*. The method guarantees *functionality*, as described by the javadoc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Roughly pointing out the relevant parts of the [`doc`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) (**Emphasis**, mine):

> **Intermediate operations are further divided into stateless and
>   stateful operations**. Stateless operations, such as filter and map,
>   retain no state from previously seen element when processing a new
>   element -- each element can be processed independently of operations
>   on other elements. **Stateful operations, such as distinct and sorted,
>   may incorporate state from previously seen elements when processing
>   new elements**
>
> **Stateful operations may need to process the entire input before
>   producing a result**. For example, one cannot produce any results from
>   sorting a stream until one has seen all elements of the stream. **As a
>   result, under parallel computation, some pipelines containing stateful
>   intermediate operations may require multiple passes on the data or may
>   need to buffer significant data**. Pipelines containing exclusively
>   stateless intermediate operations can be processed in a single pass,
>   whether sequential or parallel, with minimal data buffering

If you read further down (section on ordering):

> Streams may or may not have a defined encounter order. Whether or not
>   a stream has an encounter order depends on the source and the
>   intermediate operations. **Certain stream sources (such as List or
>   arrays) are intrinsically ordered, whereas others (such as HashSet)
>   are not. Some intermediate operations, such as sorted(), may impose an
>   encounter order on an otherwise unordered stream**, and others may
>   render an ordered stream unordered, such as BaseStream.unordered().
>   Further, some terminal operations may ignore encounter order, such as
>   forEach().

...

> For parallel streams, relaxing the ordering constraint can sometimes
>   enable more efficient execution. **Certain aggregate operations, such as
>   filtering duplicates (distinct()) or grouped reductions
>   (Collectors.groupingBy()) can be implemented more efficiently if
>   ordering of elements is not relevant**. Similarly, operations that are
>   intrinsically tied to encounter order, such as limit(), may require
>   buffering to ensure proper ordering, undermining the benefit of
>   parallelism. **In cases where the stream has an encounter order, but the
>   user does not particularly care about that encounter order, explicitly
>   de-ordering the stream with unordered() may improve parallel
>   performance for some stateful or terminal operations**. However, most
>   stream pipelines, such as the "sum of weight of blocks" example above,
>   still parallelize efficiently even under ordering constraints.

In conclusion,

- distinct will work fine with parallel streams, but as you may already know, it has to consume the entire stream before continuing and this may use a lot of memory.
- If the source of the items is an unordered collection (such as hashset) or the stream is `unordered()`, then `distinct` is not worried about ordering the output and thus will be efficient

Solution is to add `.unordered()` to the stream pipeline if you are not worried about order and would like to see more performance.

```
List<String> result2 = strList.parallelStream()
                              .unordered()
                              .map(String::toLowerCase)
                              .distinct()
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

Alas there is no (available builtin) concurrent hashset in Java (unless they got clever with [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)), so I can only leave you with the unfortunate possibility that distinct is implemented in a blocking fashion using a regular Java set. In which case, I don't see any benefit of doing a parallel distinct.

---

Edit: I spoke too soon. There might be some benefit with using parallel streams with distinct. It looks like `distinct` is implemented with more cleverness than I initially thought. See [@Eugene's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1059372/eugene) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53648162/2089675).

Comment: Was reading the docs as well for this one.. *As a result, under parallel computation, some pipelines containing stateful intermediate operations may require multiple passes on the data or may need to buffer significant data.*  seems to be the precise answer OP is looking for.

Comment: @smac well there actually *is*  a built-in concurrent `Set`. That the factory method for it is placed in `ConcurrentHashMap` does not really change that: [`newKeySet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#newKeySet())

Comment: The implementation (a java 8 version) I'm currently looking at actually uses a `ConcurrentHashMap<T, Boolean>` directly for the "parallel unordered" case, but uses a different (reduction-based) approach for "parallel ordered".

Comment: @Hulk right, exactly what I mentioned in my answer, obviously a `LinkedHashSet` would be used in case of a ordered operation; but there is one more interesting approach used internally when the source is known to be sorted

Comment: @Hulk how did you find that the implementation uses CHM for parallel unordered case. I am not able to find this in source code.

Comment: @i_am_zero I found the implementation in `DistinctOps.makeRef()` - this returns an anonymous inner class derived from `ReferencePipeline.StatefulOp` which overrides method `opEvaluateParallel()`. There is a [...]`else if (StreamOpFlag.ORDERED.isKnown(...)` - the parallel unordered case is the corresponding `else` - block (I'm looking at 1.8.0_121)

Comment: @i_am_zero seems it is still like that: [OpenJdk 11 Source](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk11/file/1ddf9a99e4ad/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/stream/DistinctOps.java) starting at line 79 (including the TODO...)

Comment: @Hulk Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You seem to miss quite a few things from the documentation you provide and the actual example.

> Stream pipeline results may be nondeterministic or incorrect if the behavioral parameters to the stream operations are **stateful**.

In your example, you don't have any stateful operations defined *by you*. Stateful in the doc means the ones the you define, not the ones that are implemented by `jdk` itself - like `distinct` in your example. But either way you could define a stateful operation that would be correct, even [Stuart Marks - working at Oracle/Java, provides such an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27872852/1059372).

So you are more than OK in the examples that you provide, be it parallel or not.

The expensive part of `distinct` (in parallel) come from the fact that internally there has to be a thread-safe data structure that would keep distinct elements; in jdk case it is a `ConcurrentHashMap` used in case the order does not matter, or a reduction using a `LinkedHashSet` when order matters.

`distinct` btw is a pretty smart implementation, it looks if your source of the stream is already distinct (in such a case it is a no-op), or looks if your data is sorted, in which case it will do a little smarter traversal of the source (since it knows that if you have seen one element, the next to come is either the same you just seen or a different one), or using a `ConcurrentHashMap` internally, etc.

Comment: I can see that `set` is used to maintain non-duplicates in case of `distinct` operation. In case of parallel streams it may consume the entire stream itself rather than going with CHM. Thoughts?

Comment: @i_am_zero not sure I follow u, care to expand your comment?

Comment: Okay. I simply want to understand how parallel streams will work in case of `distinct`? Will it consume the entire input at one go (no benefit in this case) or will it use CHM? I could not find any official reference clarifying this.

Comment: @i_am_zero either way, the entire stream will not be consumed, at once. And you dont have to look at the implementation to understand that. `Stream.of(1,2,2,3,4).peek(System.out::println).distinct().peek(System.out::println).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 2):

There won't be a problem (problem as in a wrong result) but as the [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct--) note says

> Preserving stability for distinct() in parallel pipelines is relatively expensive

But if performance is of concern and if [stability](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Ordering) is not a problem (i.e the result having a different order of elements with respect to the collection it processed ) then you follow the API's note

> removing the ordering constraint with BaseStream.unordered() may
>   result in significantly more efficient execution for distinct() in
>   parallel pipelines,

I thought why not benchmark performance of parallel and sequential streams for `distinct`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> strList = Arrays.asList("cat", "nat", "hat", "tat", "heart", "fat", "bat", "lad", "crab", "snob");

        List<String> words = new Vector<>();


        int wordCount = 1_000_000; // no. of words in the list words
        int avgIter = 10; // iterations to run to find average running time

        //populate a list randomly with the strings in `strList`
        for (int i = 0; i < wordCount; i++) 
            words.add(strList.get((int) Math.round(Math.random() * (strList.size() - 1))));





        //find out average running times
        long starttime, pod = 0, pud = 0, sod = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < avgIter; i++) {
            starttime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            List<String> parallelOrderedDistinct = words.parallelStream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
            pod += System.currentTimeMillis() - starttime;

            starttime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            List<String> parallelUnorderedDistinct =
                    words.parallelStream().unordered().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
            pud += System.currentTimeMillis() - starttime;

            starttime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            List<String> sequentialOrderedDistinct = words.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
            sod += System.currentTimeMillis() - starttime;
        }

        System.out.println("Parallel ordered time in ms: " + pod / avgIter);
        System.out.println("Parallel unordered time in ms: " + pud / avgIter);
        System.out.println("Sequential implicitly ordered time in ms: " + sod / avgIter);
    }
```

The above was compiled by open-jdk 8 and run on openjdk's jre 8 (no jvm specific arguments) on an i3 6th gen (4 logical cores) and I got these results

Seemed like after a certain  no. of elements, ordered parallel was faster and ironically parallel unordered was the slowest. The reason behind this (thanks to @Hulk) is the because of the way its implemented (using a HashSet).So a general rule would be that if you a few elements and a lot of duplication several magnitudes greater you might benefit from the `parallel()`.

1)

```
Parallel ordered time in ms: 52
Parallel unordered time in ms: 81
Sequential implicitly ordered time in ms: 35
```

2)

```
Parallel ordered time in ms: 48
Parallel unordered time in ms: 83
Sequential implicitly ordered time in ms: 34
```

3)

```
Parallel ordered time in ms: 36
Parallel unordered time in ms: 70
Sequential implicitly ordered time in ms: 32
```

The unordered parallel was twice slower than both.

Then I upped `wordCount` to `5_000_000` and these were the results

1)

```
Parallel ordered time in ms: 93
Parallel unordered time in ms: 363
Sequential implicitly ordered time in ms: 123
```

2)

```
Parallel ordered time in ms: 100
Parallel unordered time in ms: 363
Sequential implicitly ordered time in ms: 124
```

3)

```
Parallel ordered time in ms: 89
Parallel unordered time in ms: 365
Sequential implicitly ordered time in ms: 118
```

and then to `10_000_000`

1)

```
Parallel ordered time in ms: 148
Parallel unordered time in ms: 725
Sequential implicitly ordered time in ms: 218
```

2)

```
Parallel ordered time in ms: 150
Parallel unordered time in ms: 749
Sequential implicitly ordered time in ms: 224
```

3)

```
Parallel ordered time in ms: 143
Parallel unordered time in ms: 743
Sequential implicitly ordered time in ms: 222
```

Comment: Explanation: Your setup - Lots of duplicates of very few distinct strings favors the "parallel ordered"-implementation, because (at least in the version I'm looking at) that is implemented via parallel reduction to `LinkedHashSet`s - as these sets quickly converge to exactly your small set of input strings, the combining step is pretty fast. If duplicates were rare (only a few duplicates to eliminate), the outcome would likely be quite different.

Comment: @Hulk I tried it out with 40k distinct elements (8!) and yes you're right. I'll put it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

From the javadocs, parallelStream()

> Returns a **possibly** parallel Stream with this collection as its source.
>   It is allowable for this method to return a sequential stream.

*Performance:*

1. Let us consider we have a multiple stream(*luckily*) that is given to different cores of CPU. `ArrayList<T>` which has internal data representation based upon an array. Or a `LinkedList<T>` which needs more computation for splitting to be processed in parallel. `ArrayList<T>` is better in this case!
2. `stream.unordered().parallel().distinct()` has better performance than `stream.parallel().distinct()`

> Preserving stability for distinct() in parallel pipelines is
>   relatively expensive (requires that the operation act as a full
>   barrier, with substantial buffering overhead).

So, in your case it **should not be a problem**(Unless your `List<T>` does not care of order). Read below for explanation,

Lets say you have 4 elements in ArrayList,
{"a","b","a","b"}

Now if you **don't** use `parallelStream()` before calling `distinct()`, only the String at positions 0 and 1 is retained.(Preserves the order,Sequential stream)

Else, (if you use `parallelStream().distinct()`) then elements at 1 and 2 *can* be retained as distinct(It is unstable, but the result is same {"a,"b"} or it can even be {"b","a"}).

An unstable distinct operation will randomly eliminate the duplicates.

Finally,

> under parallel computation, some pipelines containing stateful
>   intermediate operations may require multiple passes on the data or may
>   need to buffer significant data