# is there any method to delete duplicate in linkedlist have I tried a method but it gives me index out of bounds exception?

Tags: java, list, data-structures, collections, linked-list

```
import java.util.*;

public class list<E> extends LinkedList<E> {
  int j=0;
  int l=0;
  LinkedList Search(Object o) {
    int[] array=new int[super.size()];
    for(int i=0; i<super.size(); i++) {
        if(o.equals(super.get(i))) {
            array[j]=i;
            j=j+1;
            continue;
        }
    }
    return Arrayfilter(array);
 }

 private LinkedList Arrayfilter(int[] i) {
    int[] aray=null;
    LinkedList<Integer> ll= new LinkedList<Integer>();
    for(int j:i){
        if((l==0)|(j!=0)){
            ll.add(j);
            l=l+1;
            continue;
        }
    }
    return ll;
 }

 boolean deleteduplicate() {
    for(int l=0; l<super.size(); l++){
      for(int i:Search(super.get(l))) {
        super.remove(i);
      }
    }
    return true;
 }
}
```

Whenever I tried that method delete duplicate () it gives me index out of bounds error how I can modify the method that it return true

I know that whenever I remove anything in for loop I reducing the size of list that giving me that error, or anything else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Comment: 1.) You are using the [*raw type* `LinkedList`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/2711488) several times. 2) You are notoriously using the opposite of the common coding style, lowerclass class names and upper case method names. This makes the code hard to read for those who want to help you. 3) You may rethink [whether `LinkedList` is the right choice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/322715/2711488) here. 4.) This brings us to one of the reasons you should [*use* collections, not subclass them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49002/2711488).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `LinkedHashSet<E>` instead of LinkedList you get that for free.

To keep your code you could use:

```
void deleteduplicate() {
   Set<E> tmp = new LinkedHashSet<>(this);
   this.clear();
   this.addAll(tmp);
}
```

Following the example in [this question].([How do I remove repeated elements from ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203984/how-do-i-remove-repeated-elements-from-arraylist#:~:text=The%20easiest%20way%20to%20remove,addAll(set)%3B))

Comment: Thanks .. I am going to use that but .is it possible declare that method in linkedlist just wondering how?

Comment: Thanks.. linkedhashset also work and order not changed t

Comment: Ah. The order would change with HashSet, but you can just change it to LinkedHashSet and get the same result but ordered. Updated

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Set to track the duplicates and a listIterator() to traverse the linked list as below

```
   public LinkedList<E> deleteDuplicate(LinkedList<E>list)
     {
        Iterator<? extends E> it=list.listIterator();
        Set<E> set = new HashSet<>();
        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            E e=it.next();
            if(set.contains(e))
               it.remove();
            else
                set.add(e);
        }
        return list;
     }
```

EDIT :

```
public LinkedList<E> deleteDuplicate(LinkedList<E>list)
    {
        Iterator<? extends E> it=list.listIterator();
        Set<E> set = new HashSet<>();
        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            E e=it.next();
            if(!set.add(e))
                it.remove();
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: The contract of `Set.add` is already sufficient to test the presence of an element, so you can simply use `while(it.hasNext()) if(!set.add(it.next())) it.remove();`, without a preceding `contains` test. Or do it even simpler: `Set<E> set = new HashSet<>(); list.removeIf(e -> !set.add(e));`.

Comment: @Holger added in EDIT : section . Thanks