# Joining 2 Arraylists JAVA

Tags: java, arraylist

> So I have this class which reads from 2 files and fills 2 Arraylists
> with Contact Objects. Now I want to Merge these Arraylists to a new
> Arraylist which then I want to Sort and eliminate duplicates. My
> problem is: How do I get the filled Arraylists to another method so I
> can do the sorting?
> Here is my Code:

```
 import java.util.List;
 import java.util.Scanner;
 
 final class Addressbook{
 
     public List<Contact> contacts1 = new ArrayList<Contact>();
 
     public List<Contact> contacts2= new ArrayList<Contact>();
 
     public List<Contact> allcontacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();
 
     public void readContacts1(Scanner scanner1) {
 
         scanner1.useDelimiter(";");
 
         while (scanner1.hasNext()) {
             final Contact contact= readContacts1(scanner1);
             contacts1.add(Contact);
 
         }
         
 
 
     }
 
     public void readContacts2(Scanner scanner2) {
 
         while (scanner2.hasNext()) {
             final Contact contact = readContacts2(scanner2);
             contacts.add(contact);
 
         }
     
         
 }
     
     public int ContactSearch1(Contact c) {
 
         for (int i = 0; i < contacts1.size(); i++)
 
             if (contacts1.get(i).equals(c))
                 return i;
         return -1;
 
     }
 
     public int ContactSearch2(Contact c) {
 
         for (int i = 0; i < contacts2.size(); i++)
 
             if (contacts2.get(i).equals(c))
                 return i;
         return -1;
 
     }
 
     private static Contact readContact1(Scanner scanner1) {
         scanner1.useDelimiter(";");
 
         final String name= scanner1.next();
         final String lastname = scanner1.next();
         final String address = scanner1.next();
         final String number = scanner1.next();
 
         final Contact contact= new Contact(name, lastname, address, number);
         return contact;
 
     }
 
     private static Contact ReadContact2(Scanner scanner2) {
         scanner2.useDelimiter(";");
 
         final String name= scanner2.next();
 
         final String lastname = scanner2.next();
 
         final String address = scanner2.next();
 
         final String number = scanner2.next();
 
         final Contact contact= new Contact(name, lastname, address, number);
         return contact;
 
     }
 

 
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried to compile your code?  It seems there are infinite loops in `readContacts1`/`readContacts2` -- these methods call themselves recursively instead of implied `readContact1`.  And why do you need so much duplicated code?

Comment: I need to read in 2 files convert them to "Contact Objects"  and do operations with these. I also need a complete list of these.Therefor I want to merge contacts1 with contacts2 but I don`t get how I can get these lists out of the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the provided code contains a lot of duplicated parts which may easily be encapsulated in a separate helper class which takes care of reading and searching the lists.

```java
final class Addressbook{

    private List<Contact> contacts1;
    private List<Contact> contacts2;
 
    private List<Contact> allContacts;

    private static class ContactHelper {
        public static List<Contact> readContacts(Scanner scanner) {
            // scanner.setDelimiter(";"); // it's better to set this parameter in the call
            List<Contact> result = new ArrayList<>();
            boolean hasData = scanner.hasNext();
            while (hasData) {
                final String name= scanner.next();
                final String lastname = (hasData &= scanner.hasNext()) ? scanner.next() : "NO_LAST_NAME";
                final String address = (hasData &= scanner.hasNext()) ? scanner.next() : "NO_ADDRESS";
                final String number = (hasData &= scanner.hasNext()) ? scanner.next() : "NO_NUMBER";

                result.add(new Contact(name, lastname, address, number));

                hasData = scanner.hasNext();
            }
            return result;
        }

        public static int indexOfContact(Contact contact, List<Contact> list) {
            Objects.requireNonNull(contact);
            Objects.requireNonNull(list);

            for (int i = 0, n = list.size(); i < n; i++) {
                if (contact.equals(list.get(i))) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Then appropriate methods to set fields `contacts1`, `contacts2` should use the helper's methods:

```java
// class AddressBook
public void readContacts1(Scanner scanner) {
    contacts1 = ContactHelper.readContacts(scanner);
}

public void readContacts2(Scanner scanner) {
    contacts2 = ContactHelper.readContacts(scanner);
}
```

A method to join the lists, sort them, and remove the duplicates can be implemented using `TreeSet` if class `Contact` implements interface `Comparable` required for sorting the contacts in *their* natural order, otherwise custom comparator must be provided.

```java
// another helper method
public static List<Contact> joinContacts(List<Contact> ... contactLists) {
    Set<Contact> sortedWithoutDups = new TreeSet<>();
    for (List<Contact> list : contactLists) {
        if (null != list) {
            sortedWithoutDups.addAll(list);
        }
    }

    return new ArrayList<>(sortedWithoutDups);
}

// setting allContacts
public void joinContacts() {
    allContacts = AddressBook.joinContacts(contacts1, contacts2);
}
```

---

This task can be resolved using Stream API (allowing for joining more than 2 lists any of which may be `null`):

```java
// AddressBook
public void joinContacts() {
    allContacts = ContactHelper.joinContactLists(contacts1, contacts2);
}

// ContactHelper
public static List<Contact> joinContactLists(List<Contact> ... lists) {
    return Arrays.stream(lists)  // Stream<List<Contact>>
                 .filter(Objects::nonNull) // filter out null lists
                 .flatMap(List::stream)  // convert to Stream<Contact>
                 .sorted()               // sort
                 .distinct()             // _and then_ remove duplicates
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
contacts1.addAll(contacts2);
contacts1.sort((o1, o2) -> o1 < o2 ? o1 : o2);
```

`contacts1.addAll(contacts2)`

This adds all contacts2 to contacts1 and contacts1 List will have all the contacts.

Here u can replace `o1 < o2` can be replaced with the logic u need to sort.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to ensure, that you do not have duplicates in your `ArrayList` is to copy your list into a `Collection` that does not allow duplicates (for example a set) and then copy it back into the `ArrayList` you need. I would recommend to check out this post for this:

[Answers to Question: I have an ArrayList, and I want to remove repeated strings from it. How can I do this?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/203992/15080083)

Ultimately your problem could be answered the following way (using the code of mentioned blog post):

```
allcontacts.addAll(contacts1);
allcontacts.addAll(contacts2);

Set<Contact> set = new HashSet<>(allcontacts);
allcontacts.clear();
allcontacts.addAll(set);
```

Now you got rid of all duplicates and merged the `ArrayLists` `contacts1` and `contacts2` into `allcontacts`.
You now only have to sort `allcontacts`, which can be done like this (if `Contact` implements `Comparable`):

```
Collections.sort(allcontacts);
```

Comment: A `TreeSet` would sort the contents directly at insert time

Comment: You can not apply `Collections.sort(..)` on a `Set`

Comment: allcontacts is defined by the user PK2121 as an ArrayList. I just copied the ArrayList into a set and the copied it back into an ArrayList and then apply Collections.sort(..). Sorry if I expressed it in a confusing way.